# Git changes modification time of files

Tags: git, msysgit

In the [GitFaq](http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F) I can read, that

> Git sets the current time as the timestamp on every file it modifies, but only those.

However, I tried this command sequence:

```
$ git init test && cd test
Initialized empty Git repository in d:/test/.git/

$ touch filea fileb

$ git add .

$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) fcaf171] first commit
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 filea
 create mode 100644 fileb

$ ls -l > filea

$ touch fileb -t 200912301000

$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r--    1 exxxxxxx Administ      132 Feb 12 18:36 filea
-rw-r--r--    1 exxxxxxx Administ        0 Dec 30 10:00 fileb

$ git status -a
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in filea
# On branch master
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in filea
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#






#       modified:   filea
#

$ git checkout .

$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 exxxxxxx Administ        0 Feb 12 18:36 filea
-rw-r--r--    1 exxxxxxx Administ        0 Feb 12 18:36 fileb
```

Why did Git change the timestamp of file `fileb`? I'd expect the timestamp to be unchanged.

Are my commands causing a problem?
Maybe it is possible to do something like a `git checkout . --modified` instead?

I am using `git version 1.6.5.1.1367.gcd48` under MinGW and Windows XP.

Comment: Candidates for the canonical question: *[What's the equivalent of Subversion's "use-commit-times" for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964470/)* (2009) and *[Checking out old files WITH original create/modified timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722)* (2010). Mercurial has [the Timestamp extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7809151) (though that does not help much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't occur on a Linux filesystem. I tested the exact scenario you described and my modification times are preserved for the files I have left untouched:

```
sean@SEAN-PC:~/Desktop/test$ ls -la tests/BusTests.*
-r--r--r-- 1 sean sean 8 2010-02-11 11:53 tests/BusTests.c
-r--r--r-- 1 sean sean 1 2010-02-11 11:51 tests/BusTests.h

sean@SEAN-PC:~/Desktop/test$ git status -a
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   tests/BusTests.c
#

sean@SEAN-PC:~/Desktop/test$ git checkout .

sean@SEAN-PC:~/Desktop/test$ ls -la tests/BusTests.*
-r--r--r-- 1 sean sean 1 2010-02-11 11:55 tests/BusTests.c
-r--r--r-- 1 sean sean 1 2010-02-11 11:51 tests/BusTests.h
```

I suspect that this is an unknown bug in the MinGW build of Git. You might want to report it to the developers: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/list

It would be interesting to see if the BusTests.h modification stamp is modified when you only checkout the modified file:

```
git checkout -- tests/BusTests.c
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, `git checkout -- tests/BusTests.c` works as expected.

Comment: I added a complete command sequence to my question ... maybe you can try to reproduce this once again?

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (incl. the redirect which is a 404).

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-files -m | xargs git co --
```

helps to checkout only the modified files. But I still can't explain, why `git checkout` causes the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a similar problem with git reset --hard as of msysgit version 1.7.0.2.
Before, it would only change timestamps of modified files.
Now, it changes timestamps of all files.
I went back to using 1.6.5.1 for that reason, because it doesn't have this problem :)