# Git clone changes file modification time

Tags: git, clone

When I clone a Git repository using the "`git clone ...`" command, all cloned files in my local repository have the same modification time with date and time as when the `git clone` command was issued.

Is there a way to clone a remote Git repository **with the actual modification time for each file**?

Comment: You can get the time of the last modification from `git log -n1 -- file`; that is what `git` is for.

Comment: I do not quite understand the statement "this is what git is for". Why mod. time is not saved just like in CVS?

Comment: @Amadan: you only get the last commit time, not the last time the file was modified.

Comment: @turnt It's not an issue... programs can change the modification times of files they create so it's a choice of the program

Comment: Candidates for the canonical question: *[What's the equivalent of Subversion's "use-commit-times" for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964470/)* (2009) and *[Checking out old files WITH original create/modified timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722)* (2010). Mercurial has [the Timestamp extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7809151) (though that does not help much).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking out old files WITH original create/modified timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722/checking-out-old-files-with-original-create-modified-timestamps)

Answer (score 41):

Git [does not record timestamp for the files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179825/6309), since it is a *Distributed* VCS (meaning the time on your computer can be different from mine: there is no "central" notion of time and date)

The official argument for not recording that metadata is explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964508/6309).

But you can find scripts which will attempt to restore a meaningful date, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284229/6309) (or a [simpler version of the same idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179876/6309)).

Comment: But it could save the local time on the remote end. How do I solve the problem with builds when files are complied based on their modification time?

Comment: @user3302761 "it could save the local time on the remote end": that is what the metastore.git approach does, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13284229/6309: stores metadata (not only timestamps) in the repo when commiting (via pre-commit hook), and re-applies them when pulling (also via hooks).

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply and suggested solutions. I saw the discussion,but the arguments for not saving mod times because git is version control system do not look strong to me. I used CVS for years and it has this feature and it does not hurt it. Indeed simple ls -ltr command shows you the order of modified files checked out from CVS repository.

Comment: Actually all solutions I saw before do not guaranty that the actual file is is in the remote repository. Git log shows commits but some commits could be still local.

Comment: The fact that builds rely on the modification time of files is actually a reason to _not_ store this as part of the metadata. If the mtime _is_ updated to the time of commit you'd have to start a clean build after checking out an older commit, since files would be considered older than the corresponding derived files and won't cause them to be rebuilt. (Assuming a build system that relies on the mtime, obviously.)

Comment: I am not talking particularly about builds. Look at my comment "... Indeed simple ls -ltr command shows you the order of modified files checked out from CVS repository".

Comment: And why would you need to re-build not modified files?

Comment: It could save UTC time, can't it?

Comment: @user626528 UTC or not, there is no guarantee that the time you are saving is the "right" one.

Comment: @VonC, you never have any guarantee that your time is right. That's not the reason to abandon using time, though.

Comment: @user626528 I agree with you, and I have seen in the past some "workaround/hacks" to record it anyway: you can see various scripts in http://stackoverflow.com/q/1964470/6309.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284229/6309) solution (as pointed in the answer) works really well. Tested on ubuntu 20.04 just now. :)

Answer (score 40):

You can retrieve the last modification date of all files in a Git repository (last commit time). See *[How to retrieve the last modification date of all files in a Git repository](https://serverfault.com/questions/401437/how-to-retrieve-the-last-modification-date-of-all-files-in-a-git-repository)*.

Then use the [touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(command)) command change the modification date:

```sh
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | while read filename; do
  unixtime=$(git log -1 --format="%at" -- "${filename}")
  touchtime=$(date -d @$unixtime +'%Y%m%d%H%M.%S')
  touch -t ${touchtime} "${filename}"
done
```

Also see my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/HackingGate/9e8169c7645b074b2f40c959ca20d738).

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. For us, this was critical so we could speed up our `Makefile` based builds.

Comment: This is the answer.  Except one change, in case of filenames with spaces, you should add quotes around the $filename.

Comment: @P.T. I see quotes have been added now

Comment: How is this the answer..  You say "You can retrieve the last modification date of all files in a git repository. (lat commit time)"  <---  That's the date and time  of the commit. That's not the date and time for the individual file. That's not a "last modification date" for the file.  That(as far as I can tell), is the date/time for the commit that involved the adding of that file. So if a bunch of files were all added in that commit, your script would give them all the same date/time even if they were days or months or years or hours  apart.

Comment: So if somebody did a first commit, on a directory of  little ruby scripts that have been written at a variety of times, and they commit it , make some chanegs, and commit again, and push it to a repo, and then they git clone it from on another computer, then it's all same date, and then they run your script, they'll only get a bunch of files stamped with one date/time, and a bunch of files stamped with another date/time, and that's it. Just for the commit dates, that's not the file's last modification date/time at all

Comment: @barlop git history is not always the history of actual edits, it can be modified by amending and rebase -i. It's a _logical_ history the author chose to present, and in it a commit is a logically _atomic_, simultaneous change to a set of files. If you want to record "file1 changed before file2", then there must exist a point between those - these must be separate commits.

Comment: Great command! This demonstrate another lack of intuitiveness & simplicity of GIT. This should be the default behavior when you clone a depository.

Answer (score 14):

Another option for resetting the mtime is [git-restore-mtime](https://github.com/MestreLion/git-tools/#git-restore-mtime).

```
sudo apt install git-restore-mtime # Debian/Ubuntu example
git clone <myurl>
cd <mydir>
git restore-mtime
```

Answer (score 8):

This Linux one-liner will fix the problem with all the files (not folders - just files) - and it will also fix the problem with files with spaces in them too:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log -1 --format="%ai {}" {} | perl -ne 'chomp;next if(/'"'"'/);($d,$f)=(/(^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d(?: \+\d\d\d\d|)) (.*)/);print "d=$d f=$f\n"; `touch -d "$d" '"'"'$f'"'"'`;'
```

Comment: Very, very nice. Cool!!!! As far as I see it, some files may not yet converted with this solution unfortunately. E.g.: 1. Files containing the character `'` (39     0027     '     APOSTROPHE), 2. Files in the root directory of the repository, 3. Files containing a `(` (could be also a `)` ). Maybe you could find the time to have a look for these specific cases, too?

Comment: That's retrieving from git repo,  so would only give commit dates. Not actual file last modification date/time.

Answer (score 6):

A shorter variant of [user11882487's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735435/git-clone-changes-file-modification-time/57352007#57352007) that I find easier to understand:

```
git ls-files | xargs -I{} git log -1 --date=format:%Y%m%d%H%M.%S --format='touch -t %ad "{}"' "{}" | $SHELL
```

Comment: Works without error, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the list of one-liners ...

```sh
for f in $(git ls-files) ; do touch -d $(git log -1 --format='%aI' "$f") "$f" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This applies to solutions in multiple previous answers:

Use the `%at` format, and then `touch -d \@$epochdelta`, to avoid date-time conversion issues.

Answer (score 1):

Running `log -1` once per file irks me so I wrote this to do them all in one pass:

```
( # don't alter any modified-file stamps:
  git diff --name-status --no-find-copies --no-renames | awk '$1="D"' FS=$'\t' OFS=$'\t'
  git log --pretty=%cI --first-parent --name-status -m --no-find-copies --no-renames
) | awk ' NF==1 { date=$1 }
          NF<2 || seen[$2]++ { next }
          $1!="D" { print "touch -d",date,$2 }' FS=$'\t'
```

which does the linux history in like ten seconds (piping all the touch commands through a shell takes a minute).

This is a good way to ruin e.g. bisecting, and I'm in the camp of ~don't even *start* down the road of trying to overload filesystem timestamps, the people who insist on doing this are apparently going to have to learn the hard way~, but I can see that maybe there's workflows where this really won't hurt you.

Whatever. But, for sure, do not do this blindly.

Comment: Can you make your answer more self-contained? E.g., does it follow/operate on the output of `git ls-files` (and instead of xargs)? What answer(s) does "Running log -1 once per file" refer to (four answers has "`log -1`")? (Use a link to the answer as user names may change at any time.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen It prints touch commands as-is, it doesn't need anything added. Pipe them through a shell, which I think the mention of  "piping all the touch commands through a shell" suggested explicitly. Any answer that runs `log -1` necessarily runs it once per file, my objection is to the method.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in Python is simpler than some of these other options, as [`os.utime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime) accepts the Unix timestamp output by the `git log` command. This example uses GitPython but it'd also work with `subprocess.run` to call `git log`.

```py
import git
from os import utime
from pathlib import Path

repo_path = "my_repo"
repo = git.Repo(repo_path)

for n in repo.tree().list_traverse():
    filepath = Path(repo.working_dir) / n.path
    unixtime = repo.git.log(
        "-1", "--format='%at'", "--", n.path
    ).strip("'")
    if not unixtime.isnumeric():
        raise ValueError(
            f"git log gave non-numeric timestamp {unixtime} for {n.path}"
        )
    utime(filepath, times=(int(unixtime), int(unixtime)))
```

This matches the results of the `git restore-mtime` command in [this answer](https://github.com/MestreLion/git-tools/#git-restore-mtime) and the script in [the highest rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55609950/2668831).

If you're doing this immediately after cloning, then you can reuse the `to_path` parameter passed to `git.Repo.clone_from` instead of accessing the `working_dir` attribute on the `Repo` object.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the solutions given so far are unreliable when they don't introduce arbitrary command injection vulnerabilities, either because they call `read` without `IFS=` and/or without `-r`, assume file names don't contain newline characters, forget to quote parameter expansions or command substitutions, forgot the `--` option delimiter, don't check exit status or embed the file names in shell code or `--format` arguments.

This is just a safer variant of the approach given in most answers. Assumes a GNU system:

```
git ls-tree -zr --name-only HEAD |
  xargs -n20 -r0P10 sh -xc '
    ret=0
    for file do
      d=$(git log -1 --format="@%at" -- "$file") &&
        touch -d "$d" -- "$file" || ret=$?
    done
    exit "$ret"' sh
```

Here also doing a few in parallel as the task is mostly CPU-bound.

To do it again after a `git pull` to only  update the recently touched files (here based on ctime and assuming GNU `find` 4.9 or newer), you can insert:

```
find -files0-from - -prune -cmin -5 -print0
```

As a pipeline component between `git ls-tree` and `xargs` to filter the files last updated in the last 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of files with modification date on Windows you could use the following command (works on PS)

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | ForEach-Object { "$(git log -1 --format="%ai" -- "$_")`t$_" } | sort
```