# emacs does not backup files in git repo

Tags: git, emacs

**emacs** does not create backups of files inside a **git** repository. I would like to have them saved, since I often rely on them for undoing some changes before committing my changes to the *git* repo.

I was using *xemacs* until recently, and it would always create the usual `*~` files at first save. But *emacs* doesn't do it if working inside a *git* project: it makes the usual backup files, when working outside the project, but not the ones inside a *git* repo.

I tried the following in my `.emacs` file without success:

```lisp
(setq make-backup-files t)
(setq backup-inhibited nil)
```

I have looked at the doc here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Making-Backups.html

and in the section about `backup-inhibited` it seems as if emacs checks each time if the file is controlled by a control version system, and in case it is, it wouldn't create the backup file. This check might be the one preventing the creation of the desired backup file. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [seen here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47144)

> if your files are under version control, then `vc-checkin` sets `backup-inhibited` to `t`.

It also mentions `completion-ignored-extensions`, but check first if you have that module activated, as [in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9phrga/anyone_got_src_working_with_emacs/): the [`lisp/vc.el`](https://github.com/typester/emacs/blob/master/lisp/vc.el).
That module [does include](https://github.com/typester/emacs/blob/aa6345a3f4f7b261e15ac2bbf3fa07954544196c/lisp/vc.el#L1241-L1243):

```
   ;; (unless vc-make-backup-files
   ;;   (make-local-variable 'backup-inhibited)
   ;;   (setq backup-inhibited t))
```

Setting `vc-make-backup-files` could help.

The "[Backup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html)" chapter does explain:

> For files managed by a version control system (see Version Control), the variable `vc-make-backup-files` determines whether to make backup files.
>   By default it is `nil`, since backup files are redundant when you store all the previous versions in a version control system

Comment: Thank you, that works. In answer to the last paragraph, emacs ~ files still have some use because they preserve the date, while files retrieved from git do not.

Comment: @PeterB Interesting point. Other system exist to restore file timestamp checked out by Git: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56266987/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55609950/6309

Comment: Thanks again. It's far more complicated than simply moving file~ to file, and also I have a deeply ingrained (and possibly irrational) aversion to using "touch" to backdate files; but it's good to know.