# How to deploy only changed files in Azure DevOps Pipeline Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using ADO pipelines to deploy a legacy website. Build pipeline retrieves the website directory tree from Git, publishes it as is to the pipeline and the release pipeline executes a batch file that copies the files to a network share using ROBOCOPY with flags to only process the changed files.

The problem is that the Publish task in the build pipeline resets all the timestamps and ROBOCOPY ends up copying the entire 5,000+ file web site, which takes almost 10 minutes.

Is there any way to publish artifacts without changing the timestamp on the files?

Comment: Maybe try to find a way to get the files on there without using Publish? FTP, perhaps, into a staging folder, and then ROBOCOPY from that?

Comment: Are you sure it is the publish step?  I would think the git clone operation that feeds into the publish would probably be updating the timestamp.  If that is the case, maybe you can review similar answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55609950/10761889

Comment: Git retrieves the files with timestamp intact. The agent staging (s) folder has the correct timestamp. The release folder on the Agent has all timestamps set to the release date/time.