# Git archive preserve time

Tags: git, unix, tar

I have some files in my Git repository:

```
...
-rw-r--r--  1 dimti dimti 11489 мар  2 21:54 wp-settings.php
...
```

After executing the command

```
git archive --format=tar HEAD > repo.tar
```

I fetch my files in the tar archive, but the modify time is wrong:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 dimti dimti 11115 мар  5 21:55 wp-settings.php
```

How can I say to Git archive - preserve the modification time on files in the tar archive?

Comment: Candidates for the canonical question: *[What's the equivalent of Subversion's "use-commit-times" for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964470/)* (2009) and *[Checking out old files WITH original create/modified timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722)* (2010). Mercurial has [the Timestamp extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7809151) (though that does not help much).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and tag it first, in order to use that tag, or use the commit ID

The [`git archive` man](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) page mentions:

> `git archive` behaves differently when given a tree ID versus when given a commit ID or tag ID.
>
> - In the first case (tree ID like HEAD) the current time is used as the modification time of each file in the archive.
> - In the latter case (commit ID or tag ID) **the commit time as recorded in the referenced commit object is used instead**.

So in your case (using "[How to retrieve the hash for the current commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949391/6309)"):

```
git archive --format=tar $(git rev-parse HEAD) > repo.tar
```

Comment: Hi. Your answer - not solve my question. Yes. i added "HEAD" into the command git archive. But my question - how to preserve modify times on files after execution git archive (files in tar archive - with other modify time vs original files in git repo)

Comment: @AlexanderDemidov the tar would only keep the original time if you are *not* using `HEAD` for the `git archive`

Comment: NB: using a commit ID like this does *not* use the exact time a specific file was modified but the date of the referenced commit. If one needs to restore all the original dates then something like this is needed (currently): http://stackoverflow.com/a/22638823/1905491