# git commit only timestamp modification of a file

Tags: git

I have two files, `file1` and `file2`. I modified `file1` and didn't touch `file2`. After commit, CI started which checks modification dates of `file1` and `file2`. If `file2` is older, build tool generates its own version of `file2` from `file1` and compares the results (generated `file2` and `file2` which is in repo). If there is no match the error is generated.

I don't want to modify `file2` and have no way to modify the build pipeline. The question is, how to commit only timestamp modification of `file2` so CI doesn't touch it? I want to make `file2` newer than `file1`.

Please don't ask why CI is configured in such way. This is a big project with lot of contributors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to commit file modification time with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182917/how-to-commit-file-modification-time-with-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not store *file* timestamps.

The unit of storage in Git is the commit.  A *commit* (as a whole) has a timestamp.  In fact, each commit has *two* timestamps, namely the author timestamp and the committer timestamp.  These two timestamps are part of the commit's metadata.  And, of course, a commit stores a snapshot of all of your files.  But that's *all* of your files, *without* timestamps.

This means that the answer to the question in your title is a resounding *no*.  **Even if Git itself set timestamps on files** (it doesn't), you could not make it set the timetsamp on `file2` without it also setting that on `file1` (because either you'd set all the timestamps on all files from the author or committer timestamp, or—as Git actually works today—you'd set none of them on any files).  There are only the two timestamps in the commit, and if you're going to apply them, how do you know which file(s) should get them?

The way the underlying operating system sees timestamp updates on *your* files in *your* work-tree is this: when your Git conducts a `git checkout` or `git switch` to move from whatever commit you have out now to whatever other commit you'd like to have out, your Git observes that this requires replacing the contents of some files (and perhaps removing some files and creating some files).  So Git replaces the contents of those files, and/or removes and/or creates some files as required.  This action causes your *operating system* to change the timestamps on those files.

A CI build system may or may not work the same way.  Some CI systems might keep a work-tree full of files from a previous build; others might not.<sup>1</sup>  In any case, you cannot get *Git* to set date-stamps like this.<sup>2</sup>  You will have to find some other way to deal with your CI system.

(If your CI system has a standard work-tree, you can get it to update its in-work-tree copy of `file2` by ... changing `file2` so that Git must extract it when changing commits.  But this is what you said you did *not* want.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It seems pretty common, in these build systems, to *not* keep a work-tree, and instead, to run a `git diff` to compare *file content* from a previously-built, but long since removed, work-tree to that in a proposed new build that has been extracted into a fresh work-tree.  If the file contents of particular files have changed, those files get re-built.  Some Jenkins setups do this manually for instance.  Bazel apparently formalizes this by computing hash checksums and comparing the checksums: if a checksum matches a previous build, it just re-uses the previous build's artifacts.

<sup>2</sup>People have written various Git hooks that go through and whack on file ownership and/or permissions, e.g., based on the contents of a committed file.  This technique could also be used to set the OS's timestamps.  But such a script would in general just be part of the CI system.

Answer (score 0):

I give you 2 method:

**The first is the following and is clear and safe**:

```
git rm --cached <file>
git add <file>
```

This should put the new file into the index regardless of what was previously there.

**The second is the following (but pay attention this is only a workaround)**:

```
touch file.dat
git add file.dat
```

basically, force git to recognize that the file might be changed so that it acutally checks if it has really been changed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've tried both methods but after applying them `git status` says *nothing to commit*

Comment: Did you actually add the file? It should be untracked after git rm --cached and staged after git add

Comment: Yes, after `git rm` it is untracked and I can commit. But after `git add` - nothing to commit. I even tried `touch` between `git rm` and `git add`, but it didnt help

Comment: this is really unusual.... you can provide to me a snapshot of the shell in which you execute the command?