# Add files while preserving the modification time

Tags: git

I have an old archive (`tar.gz`) of source code from 2020. I have decided to check this in git to start incremental modification. But what I want is, on my initial commit, the files should have the original modification timestamp (as shown in `ls -ltr`) that I get when I extract the `tar.gz`. By doing that, I want to leave a message for anyone browsing the repo later that the original files were from 2020.

But when I add the files to git, commit and change branch and switch back to original one again, the file modification times (as in `ls -ltr`) changes to the commit timestamp.

Is there a way to preserve the original modification times in the first commit?

Comment: Git by itself doesn't [reserve timestamps, it only has commit timestamps. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1964470/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/2179722/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/36289950/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+preserve+timestamp , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+preserve+file+modification+time

Comment: You can set the author date to 2020 and the commit date to right now.

Comment: Changing commit date to 2020 (if it is possible) will make every file having the same date.

Comment: Looks like it is not at all possible, so just for history, may be I can record the modification times using ls -lR in a text file and commit that too.

Comment: "*Changing commit date to 2020 (if it is possible) will make every file having the same date.*" No. Setting author/committer date only set the dates for **commit**, not files. If you checkout older commit the dates will be new dates, i.e. now, not even the dates of that old commit.

Comment: I have a script [`set-commit-date.py`](https://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=blob_plain;f=set-commit-date.py) (see it in my repository https://git.phdru.name/git-scripts.git/). I wrote it for a similar purpose: it parses `git log` once and for every file in a repository it finds a commit where the file was last committed; then it sets the file timestamps to the time of the commit.

Answer (score 2):

When Git checks out files, it doesn't set the modification time explicitly.  Files which need to be updated are updated with the default timestamp, and files which do not are left unchanged.  This functionality makes tools like Make work properly and is not configurable.

If you want to set things like specific permissions, ownership, or timestamps, then the tool to do that is called `mtree`.  This is a BSD utility (available in Debian as `mtree-netbsd`), and you can use it to create a manifest with certain tags based on the current state of the tree.  You can then `mtree -U` using that same manifest, to modify the owner, group, and permissions of files at a later time.

Note that you'll need to do some minor editing of the contents to exclude things like the `.git` directory, which you won't want to include.  That will be easier to do if you convert the manifest first with `mtree -C -f MANIFEST`, which puts it in a format with one file per line.

Comment: `mtree -tU` AFAIU, `mtree -U` alone doesn't restore timestamps.

Comment: The version I have (from Debian unstable) is not documented to have a `-t` option and lists restoring timestamps as part of `-U`.

Comment: I read the docs at https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to preserve the original modification times in the first commit?

No. Git does not store file timestamps. From Git's point of view, in a commit there are the AuthorDate and CommitDate timestamps. You can set those timestamps to whatever you'd like, but in a single commit you can only have two different timestamps recorded in the repo.

It seems your actual goal is:

> I want to leave a message for anyone browsing the repo later that the original files were from 2020.

Note when you clone a repo, all of the local file timestamps will be right *now* which is when the files were created on your machine. In order to convey the information to the user, I might suggest one or more of these:

1. Run your `ls -ltr` command (or perhaps `ls -ltrR` to include every file) and output it to a text file and mention the file in the README for the repo. (Or if there aren't many files you could list them directly at the end of the README.) Commit the text file(s) so that anyone who wants to can lookup the original timestamps of any file.
2. In your initial commit, put some details about the repo in the commit message that explain what you want known. You could also use this in conjunction with #1 to reference a README file with more details.
3. You could break the code into chunks and create commits for each one, with a specified datetime of your choosing for the AuthorDate of each commit. (I'd leave the CommitDate as "now" so it's obvious that they aren't the original commits.) In theory you could do one commit for every file with a different AuthorDate but that seems like overkill. Note that even if you do this, the cloned repo won't show those timestamps, but someone viewing the history of the repo will understand that you wish it to be known that those files were committed at about those times.

Comment: Yes, I had done something similar to what you suggested in 1. Captured output from ls -lR (R for recursive) and tree and checked in.