# Can Git be configured to set file dates based on the last commit date?

Tags: git

I'd like to know if Git be configured to set file dates based on the last commit date?

Currently when I checkout a branch it seems that the file dates are set to the current date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458042/restore-files-modification-time-in-git

Comment: Any reason you want to do this? Since git is snapshot based, all files will be the same date.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, do it in the post-checkout hook.

> This hook can be used to perform repository validity checks, auto-display differences from the previous HEAD if different, or set working dir metadata properties.