# git: how to retrieve all files as of a certain date

Tags: git

I'm sure this can be done (?) (in clearcase it would be quite simple).

Comment: Note: In distributed systems (like Git) the recorded dates and times may not be 100% reliable or accurate since they may be recorded on a myriad of machines. Hopefully most machines are reasonably close to the “real time”, but there may be oddball outliers lurking in the network of contributors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget [file timestamp are not recorded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722/git-checking-out-old-file-with-original-create-modified-timestamps) in a DVCS like Git.
Only commit timestamp are there, and you can checkout easily a commit from a certain date.

```
git checkout master@{1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago}
```

(Note: such a checkout would give you a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009))

---

In ClearCase, this is easy **provided you set the "preserve file time" option to true**.
(if not, you actually record the checkin time of each file, which is a bit like the Git commit timestamp, except for every files)

Comment: Ok, but there's an additional complication. My repository is a clone of a remote repository. When I give a date, it says that the log only goes back to the date when my repository was cloned. How can I make use of the history of the remote repository?

Comment: @steve: by using the remote refspec instead of a local one. See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions: `git checkout /refs/remotes/master@{...}`

Comment: fatal: '/refs/remote/master@{2010-06-04}' is outside repository

Comment: @steve: true, I don't have yet the right syntax. Still looking.

Comment: The `ref@{time}` syntax uses the reflog. Reflogs are local. That is why steve's log only goes back to the date it was cloned.

Answer (score 15):

Use `git log` to determine a suitable revision to switch to, e.g.:

```
git log --since='2010-04-01' --until='2010-04-02'
```

This will show all the commits on 2010-04-01, so just pick the one that corresponds to the instant you want the files for, and note its commit id. Then just use `git checkout COMMIT-ID` to switch the workspace to that commit. This will detach your workspace (HEAD) from the current branch, use `git checkout master` to return.

Comment: I've currently run into the problem that `git checkout master@{<date>}` does not work (as the selected date is not in the reflog). Your solution would remedy this, But is this the *only* solution to this? It seems a bit clunky to use two commands with a bit of parsing in between.

Comment: ... I suppose, something like this works: `git checkout $(git log -n 1 --until='2017-04-02:00:00:00' --pretty='%H')` but still looks rather hacky.

Answer (score 3):

first, you have to get the string that identify the commit:

```
git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" origin/master
```

it prints the string (for instance XXXX), copy it and do this command:

```
git checkout XXXX
```