# Git how to prevent local modification of public commits

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I already added receive.denyNonFastforwards and receive.denyDeletes on my git central repo server. Now I would like to block local history modifcation if the commit was already pushed to the central repo (just like mercurial does by default), I suppose I can use a hook but I couldn't find any example.

Is this a strange configuration?

It sounds like a basic safeguard that anyone using git should have activated and I'm quite surprised for the lack of example hooks.

Comment: I think you can just deny forced pushes, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent local history modification by using [Client-Side Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks), much like you would with [Server-Side Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks).

[Here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#Client-Side-Hooks) are some examples of client-side hook code. Near the end of that page is a pre-rebase script that does something close to what you're looking for.

Note that client-side hooks cannot be added to a repository in such a way that they will automatically be set up in downstream repos:

> Because hooks aren’t transferred with a clone of a project, you must distribute these scripts some other way and then have your users copy them to their .git/hooks directory and make them executable. You can distribute these hooks within the project or in a separate project, but Git won’t set them up automatically.

Comment: I'm aware of Client-side hooks, I was looking for an example of no public history modification hook

Comment: The link provided in the answer refers to a page that has an example pre-rebase hook that checks to see if the commits have already been pushed to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial offers some way to deal with mutable chagenset (changesets that you can reorder/rewrite). For instance with the [ChangeSet Evolution plugin](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangesetEvolution).

The possibility is more limited on the server side with git (you can deny the `push --force` with the two config mentioned in the question)

You cannot easily enforce a hook on the client side, since it needs to be activated, and can be bypassed with `git commit --no-verify`.

But before Git 1.8.5, there was a [pre-rebase client hook called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26702544/6309) .

After Git 1.8.5, you can do as a client [a **git push --force-with-lease**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18505634/6309):

> You assume you took the lease on the ref when you fetched to decide what the rebased history should be, and **you can push back only if the lease has not been broken**.

That allows some freedom on the client side, and a safer forced push on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very close, if not the same question as Strategy for Preventing or Catching Git History Rewrite

To sum it up you can enable

> git config --system receive.denyNonFastforwards true

and

> git config --system receive.denyDeletes true

Or write a post receive hook to reject anything you determine is a rewrite