# git push should fail if remote branch was deleted-how?

Tags: git, github

Couldn't locate myself, so reaching out for help experts!

I am working on a branch, did my changes and want to commit. meanwhile someone deleted this branch on github. Now if I push, a new branch shows up on github, which we don't like. I want the push to fail if the remote branch (which has been it's tracking remote branch) no more exists. This is because I may be unaware of remote branch deletion and I do not want to check each time I want to push using git branch -avv and git remote prune and other commands.

Please clarify, Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want it to fail?

Comment: just because I do not want to explicitly create branch on github that was deleted for a specific purpose and if someone again creates this branch with new changes from past traces that they pulled before branch was deleted, it messes up everything.

Comment: How about overwriting 'git push origin master' with bash function and check before pushing....

Comment: @Mannu - Thanks for commenting, could you give more insight please? sorry, with Git, I am still a git :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't routinely clean up your local environment with `git pull --prune`, your local environment will still be aware of old remote tracking branches, even if they've been deleted on the remote repository.

If it's hugely important to your workflow, the best way to ensure this doesn't happen again is to:

1. Set up your environment to do this with every pull by default: `git config --global fetch.prune true`
2. As practice, make sure to pull before every push.

Then, if you're working locally on a branch and its remote tracking branch has been deleted, you should get this message:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> <branch>
```

Comment: thanks for the details, but doesn't simply seem working. I do push with the command format _git push remote_name current_branch:remote_branch_.

Comment: Did you try `git pull --prune`? Then, try `git branch -al` to see if all of the remote tracking branches listed locally match the actual remote branches.

Comment: interesting though, if I try simple command _git push_, this is more misleading. it says nothing to commit. but git status shows _use "git push" to publish your local commits_.

Comment: after executing _git pull prune origin_ I tried to push again with same command format _git push remote_name local_branch_name:remote_branch_name_. Now I am getting a different error as below.
_$ git push b1 origin:b1
fatal: 'b1' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository._

Comment: This is what happening as a whole, I gave all the sequence of commands to you here.

Comment: appreciate your time Briana, would request you to go through the Git responses I posted below. sorry, took time in figuring out how to bring them in...thanks !!!!

Comment: @San: your quote has `prune` without two leading hyphens.  @Briana: `git pull` does not document `--prune`.  It is a valid argument to `git fetch`, and the `git config` suggestion is entirely correct, but `git pull` may pass `--prune` on to `git merge` instead of to `git fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you may want to use both `git push --force-with-lease` *and* `git fetch --prune`.  The `--force-with-lease` option requires that the Git on both the local and remote be not too terribly old, being at least version 1.8.5.  Any modern distribution has this, but certain unnamed Linux distributions still use Git version 1.7 (!).  (Git 2.7.2 and later also report the push result a bit better.)

Note that this is ***not*** `git pull --prune` (`--prune` is not documented as a flag to `git pull`), it is **`git fetch --prune`**.  (Using `--prune` *might* work with `git pull`, in some versions of Git.  It's just not documented as being supported.)

#### Discussion (theory of operation)

First, let's note that the opposite of `push` is actually `fetch` (not `pull`), and that `git pull` starts by running `git fetch`.  In Git, running `git pull` essentially runs `git fetch` for you, and then runs `git merge` or `git rebase` for you.  Until you are very familiar with Git, I believe you are better off running each step separately.  For one thing, it's possible for either step to fail, and the action to take to recover from such failures is quite different depending on which step failed.  For another, you may want to inspect incoming changes before doing a merge or rebase (or perhaps even choosing to do something else entirely).  If you use `git pull` you are forced to decide on merge-vs-rebase *before* you have the information needed to make that decision.

In any case, it is the `git fetch` operation that connects your Git to the Git on the remote.  Once your Git and their Git are talking (usually over an Internet connection), your Git gets, from their Git, a list of all their branches and corresponding commit hashes.  The `--prune` option in `git fetch` tells your Git to remove, from your remote-tracking branches, any branches that your Git can tell that their Git no longer has.

More specifically, consider the case of `origin`.  Your Git has remote-tracking branches named `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and so on, but the *reason* it has these is that your Git called up their Git over the Internet-phone and their Git told your Git "I have a branch named `master` and a branch named `develop`", so *your* Git made *your* `origin/master` to track their `master`, and made your `origin/develop` to track their `develop`, and so on.  Now your Git calls up their Git on the Internet-phone, and this time their Git says "I have `master` and `feature`" but says nothing about `develop`.  Since their Git is telling you all about *all* of their branches, it's clear that they no longer have a `develop`.

Your Git now has to decide: Do we discard `origin/develop` since they no longer have a `develop`?  Or, do we keep `origin/develop` just in case you were still using it for something?  The default is that your Git will keep it.  Using `--prune` tells your Git that you would like your Git to discard it.  As noted in [Briana Swift's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631502/1256452), you may want to use `git config` to set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your global (user-specific) and/or local (repository-specific) settings, so that these `git fetch` operations *automatically* discard such branches.

(Note that when `git pull` invokes `git fetch`, `pull` tells `fetch` to bring over only *one* branch to its remote-tracking equivalent.<sup>1</sup>  This also inhibits pruning other remote-tracking branches—another reason to avoid `git pull`.  Admittedly, if you have a very slow Internet connection, it may improve the speed of the `fetch` step to bring over only objects needed for the one branch.)

#### Asymmetry of `fetch` vs `push`

Unless you set up Git in a very odd way,<sup>2</sup> it's always safe to run `git fetch` and pick up all the updates from a remote.  The reason is that you work off *local* branches.  You check out `master` and/or `develop` and/or `feature`, and at most, you set up these local branches to `--track` a remote-tracking branch like `origin/master`.  This kind of tracking simply tells `git status` to report how far ahead and/or behind you are, and makes it more convenient to run `git rebase` and/or `git merge`.

When you run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`, your Git calls up their (origin's) Git over the Internet-phone, gets a list of all branches, and *receives* (downloads to your repository) all the objects you need to track their branches and update your remote-tracking branches.  Your Git then updates your remote-tracking branches.  If you select pruning, your Git also deletes any obsolete remote-tracking branches.  Since the things you depend on are in your *local* branches, and this only affects *remote-tracking* branches, it's safe.

When you ask your Git to `git push` to the remote, however, the situation is different.  This time your Git *sends* objects (starting with commits and/or tags, and adding any trees and files needed by those commits and/or tags) to the remote.  Then, after sending all those objects, your Git sends a series of "update a branch or tag" requests.

With a regular (non-`--force`) push, your Git sends a "please, if you like, set this branch to this new commit ID" request, one for each branch to update.  With a `--force` push, your Git sends a more forceful "set this branch to this new commit ID" command.  If you are sending tags, your Git sends the same requests or commands, but for tags.  (These all have a general form and since Git acquired notes, your Git may send notes update requests or commands too.  The command-ness is reduced to a single "force flag", and in fact, you can set or clear it on a per-reference basis using the `+` syntax: `git push remote l1:r1 +l2:r2 l3:r3` has one force update, for remote reference *`r2`*, and two polite requests, for remote references *`r1`* and *`r2`*.)

Their Git now has a chance to inspect these change requests / commands, using built-in rules and also any rules they (the owners of the remote Git) have chosen to implement in their `pre-receive` and `update` hooks.  The default is to refuse a polite request to update a branch if it is not a fast-forward, and to refuse *any* polite request to update a tag.<sup>3</sup>  Commands—requests with the force flag set—are still allowed, and if the operation *creates or deletes* the branch or tag, it is allowed whether or not it has a force flag.  In any case, the hooks may refuse the update (although they cannot *allow* an update that would have been refused by the default rules).

#### `--force-with-lease`

These rules work fairly well for most situations, but there are some situations where they do not quite suffice.  Force-pushes of rebase operations are one such situation, and your particular desire—to update a branch on the remote Git if and only if that branch actually exists—are another.  This is where `--force-with-lease` comes in.

Note that any time we split an operation into "fetch from remote, then push to remote", we have a problem: there is no guarantee that our push, the one we do right after we do a fetch, is the *only* push<sup>4</sup> operation that happens after the fetch.  For instance, suppose we run `git fetch --prune origin && git rev-parse origin/foo && git push origin foo` on our machine, and Bob runs `git push origin :foo` on Bob's machine, and Bob is using the same remote we are, and Bob's machine sneaks his "delete branch foo" in between our fetch and our push?  We finish our fetch and start checking to make sure `origin/foo` is still valid.  Then Bob runs his push, deleting branch `foo`.  Then, on our machine, we've decided that branch `foo` does indeed exist on the remote—it did until Bob just deleted it!—and we go to push `foo`, and we succeed by creating it.

(The same thing can happen with a rebase-and-force-push: we think we have everything from `origin/foo`; we rebase it all, while Bob pushes his change; then we force-push our rebase and lose Bob's change.  Of course, in general we should not be doing this unless everyone, including Bob, has agreed that we're allowed to rebase that branch.  Bob can recover from this since Bob still has Bob's version of `foo`.  But it's annoying at best.)

The `--force-with-lease` option is designed for these cases.  The general idea is that, instead of simply commanding the other Git to set a reference, we tell the other Git *two* things: "set a reference" and "we believe it's currently set to <value>".  In both our case and the rebase case, what we should do here is tell the remote Git the value we have stored in our remote-tracking branch: we believe `refs/heads/foo` is currently `a123456...`, and *if that's correct*, we command the other Git to set it to `b987654...` instead.

If Bob sneaks in a push that changes or deletes branch `foo`, our belief—that it's currently `a123456...`—becomes incorrect.  The remote Git answers our command with "well, I might have obeyed, but you were wrong about the value of the reference."  This closes the race between "fetch to obtain the old value" and "update to set the new value".  It does mean that whoever loses this race must start over, if appropriate, but that was always going to happen.

Note that on your Git's side, where you specify the `--force-with-lease` argument, there are a lot of ways to specify which value you expect.  The simplest, however, is to let your Git fetch the value from your remote-tracking branch, and that is what you get by default.  You can therefore ignore most of the optional values listed in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html), although if you want to be particularly paranoid, you can take note of the "experimental" note and make it explicit:

```
expect=$(git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/$branch) || exit 1
git push $remote --force-with-lease=refs/heads/$branch:$expect refs/heads/$branch
```

(I believe that after this much time, the experiment should be declared a success and `--force-with-lease` should not change. :-) )

Note, incidentally, that `--force-with-lease` is very safe, and maybe should even be the default.  The only pushes that are allowed without it, that are rejected with it, are those where your push either resurrects (in fast-forward fashion) a commit that was explicitly deleted from the tip of a branch on the remote, or creates a new branch with the same name that an old branch once had (this last one is just your case, resurrecting a deleted branch).

---

<sup>1</sup>This requires that your Git be at least version 1.8.4.  In older versions, Git did not even update the remote-tracking branch.  This may suppress all pruning entirely; I have not investigated.

<sup>2</sup>In particular, if you depend on remote-tracking branches *instead of* local branches, or if you configure a fetch mirror (so that there are no remote-tracking branches and all local branches are simply force-copied from the remote), fetching can then lose objects you were depending on.

<sup>3</sup>In Git versions before 1.8.2, tag updates used branch update rules, so remotes allowed fast-forward operations on tags, by default.

<sup>4</sup>Or indeed any update, if the remote Git, on its remote machine, is actually local to some *other* users who *log in* to that remote machine, who are locally doing local things to their local Git.

Comment: Thanks much for wonderful explanation, learning a lot from you guys today, not sure how can I be thankful. Let me post what I finally got in my next update.

Answer (score 0):

finally, the option *--force-with-lease* worked, but what I wanted was seen only by appending  *origin b1:b1*. Below is the complete trace of my recent trails. So this means, is it advised to use complete form of syntax all times while using Git? i.e. never say just *git push* but say *git push remote-name local-branch-name:remote-branch-name* ? Learning git is not only fun, but scary.

```
$ git pull
From https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/b1
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/b1'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

$ git fetch --prune

$ vi README.md

$ git push --force-with-lease
Everything up-to-date

$ git push
Everything up-to-date

$ git status
On branch b1
Your branch is based on 'origin/b1', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git commit -am "dd"
[b1 9026fd5] dd
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git config --global fetch.prune
true

$ git push --force-with-lease
Everything up-to-date

$ git status
On branch b1
Your branch is based on 'origin/b1', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git push
Everything up-to-date

$ git push --force-with-lease
Everything up-to-date

$ git push --force
Everything up-to-date

$ git push --force-with-lease origin b1:b1
To https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git
 ! [rejected]        b1 -> b1 (stale info)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git'

$ git push origin b1:b1
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.18 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git
 * [new branch]      b1 -> b1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this workflow again here below. Interestingly, *git config --global fetch.prune*  seems insignificant, unless it is true by default, even when it is null. I emptied it, yet seems same response.

```
$ git config --global fetch.prune ""

$ git config --global fetch.prune

$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/userid/repo.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/userid/repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master                 tracked
    refs/remotes/origin/b1 stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    b1     merges with remote b1
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)

$ git remote prune origin
Pruning origin
URL: https://github.com/userid/repo.git
 * [pruned] origin/b1

$ vi README.md

$ git commit -am "ddd"
[b1 3c20f89] ddd
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git push
Everything up-to-date

$ git push  --force-with-lease origin
Everything up-to-date

$ git push --force-with-lease origin b1:b1
To https://github.com/userid/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        b1 -> b1 (stale info)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/userid/repo.git'

$ git push origin b1:b1
Counting objects: 17, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 1.40 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 17 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/userid/repo.git
 * [new branch]      b1 -> b1
```

Comment: so shall we accept @torek's advice _--force-with-lease_  as final answer if I am not missing anything? but for me to enforce my developers to use this always is a challenge, so I assume I will still have to hang around with my issue of _reappearing deleted branches_ at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `pre-push` hook.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    git ls-remote | if grep -q $remote_ref$
        then
            exit 0
        else
            echo $remote_ref does not exist, not pushing
            exit 1
        fi
done
```

I haven't taken a full test of this hook. The known issue is you cannot create a new branch in the remote repo by `git push` with this hook enabled.

Comment: thanks for sharing and helping to learn about these. Would surely see if we can adapt this, but we are not there yet.

Comment: @San maybe you could use some tool that provides authority management instead. We use Gerrit.

Comment: cool, just saw the introduction, looks like a worthy addition. Thank you so much again @ElpieKay

Answer (score 0):

Note: Git 2.10+ [documents a more precise use of git push `--force-with-lease`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e6747627865347a534e7106bb1d14e32867b234d/Documentation/git-push.txt#L205-L211).

See [commit 9eed4f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9eed4f3711a605ab2d9b986357879a09a6d54f36) (04 Aug 2016) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 64ac39a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64ac39af7020f3a8bc52d51137804ce9f46baf66), [commit eee98e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eee98e74f928a49c310038c77026ebc04e6cf4b2) (26 Jul 2016), and [commit d132b32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d132b32b4e3146e4aa5a719418f85d6db1134140) (25 Jul 2016) by [John Keeping (`johnkeeping`)](https://github.com/johnkeeping).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e674762](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6747627865347a534e7106bb1d14e32867b234d), 10 Aug 2016)</sup>

> `--force-with-lease=<refname>:<expect>` will protect the named ref (alone),
>   if it is going to be updated, by requiring its current value to be
>   the same as the specified value `<expect>` (which is allowed to be
>   different from the remote-tracking branch we have for the refname,
>   or we do not even have to have such a remote-tracking branch when
>   this form is used).
>   If `<expect>` is the empty string, then the named ref must not already exist.
>
> ### push: allow pushing new branches with `--force-with-lease`
>
> If there is no upstream information for a branch, it is likely that it
>   is newly created and can safely be pushed under the normal fast-forward
>   rules.
>   Relax the `--force-with-lease` check so that we do not reject these branches immediately but rather attempt to push them as new branches, using the null SHA-1 as the expected value.
>
> In fact, it is already possible to push new branches using the explicit
>   `--force-with-lease=<branch>:<expect>` syntax, so all we do here is make
>   this behaviour the default if no explicit "`expect`" value is specified.

Keep in mind, as detailed in Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), that this push option could be ignored in some cases: see "[`push --force-with-lease` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726130/6309)".