# Re-run a PR commit?

Tags: git, github

I need to PR my branch again or in other words re-run my PR commit.  Build failed and it was because the branch name itself was upper case and was sending that as part of an S3 bucket name when sending a call to the S3 API.  So I need to kinda revert it, commit a toLower in my code, and re-pr the branch.

Is this possible?

Another option would be to rename the branch itself to lower-case..same text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of revert use `git commit --amend` or `rebase` and update the branch with [force-pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672221/7976758).

Comment: can I do just a git commit then force? How will that trigger a "pr" commit rather than a regular commit though?  Travis needs to rebuild and set the feature branch value and in order to do that you have to PR a branch

Comment: also I want my commit message to be a bulleted list of items that I did, how can I do that?

Comment: I just did a commit then force push for now, I have an old commit that keeps causing merge conflicts when I try to rebase and I can't get around it.  I try to skip that commit during rebase but it doesn't let me.

Comment: 1. You don't need forced push after a regular commit. You only need it after commit editing. There is no such thing as "PR" commits; commits are added to an existing PR when you push the branch that is PR'd. 2 [Bulleted lists — help at Github](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/#lists).

Comment: no I did a force commit when the branch was still in PR state

Comment: Amend, rebase, filter-branch. In strict sense these are not editing because commits are nver changed — instead, git creates new commits and move branch pointer. This branch moving is exactly the cause for forced push.