# Reset remote git branch to previous pointer in commit tree

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need to change a remote git branch to point to a previous commit in the commit tree.

I have four branches: master, ui, test, release.  Master and UI are parallel development branches that are merged often.  Test and release branches point to previous commits on master.

A coworker screwed up (don't ask) and did:

```
git checkout release
git reset --hard origin/ui
git push
```

And now I have been tasked with fixing it.  My googlefu is failing me and while I can fix the release branch back to how it was on my local repo, I can't figure out how to push the change to the remote server (origin).  I can't do revert because of all the merging between master and ui.  I tried

```
branch -f release <SHA1>
```

and if I push I get

```
! [rejected]  release -> release (non-fast-forward)
```

and it tells me I need to fast forward before I can push.  I also tried

```
git reset --hard <SHA1>
```

with the same result.  I found lots of help on removing previous commits to a remote repository but I am failing to find directions on how to move the pointer backwards on a commit tree.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `push --force` or better yet `push --force-with-lease`

Comment: Do note that force push is a destructive action and that you should be 110% sure you're doing the right thing first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next step is a simple `git push --force` (communicating fist to your colleagues they will have to fetch and then reset their own `master` branch)

Note sure a force-with-lease is needed here, considering [it interacts badly with any fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726130/6309).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is `git push --force`, which is why I marked it as the answer.  But in my case there was one additional step.  On force pushing to bitbucket I got the error:

```
remote: permission denied to force push branch release
To https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] release-> release (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git'
```

(For some reason I missed reading the "permission denied" line when I did it the first time.)

To fix this, in the bitbucket repo you need to go to
`Setting -> Branch permissions -> Edit branch permission (little pencil icon) -> Check "Allow rewriting branch history" -> Save`

This fixed the permission issue.

Comment: Good feedback, which does complete my answer.+1