# Side effects on a periodic git fetch

Tags: git, networking, server

Let's say i have a code like this:

```
git fetch &&  git diff origin origin/master --quiet || echo "untracked"
```

And i want it to run periodically. Let's say, once a second, or once per five seconds and so on.

If this code outputs "untracked", or in other words, if there is an update on the remote,i will run a `git pull` to update the local code.

Question is: Is it bad to do something like this? I mean, i know that it would be a constant request on the remote server. But, is it bad? And apart from that, is there any other side effects? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you going to never switch the local branch? Are you never going to commit a change?

Comment: @choroba Yeah, that's right. I just want to pull stuff, never commit.

Comment: Running a git command creates and delete the '.git/index.lock' file. Running multiple git commands in parallel into the same repository will make some calls to fail quite often... But if you run it each 2 minutes could be OK.

Comment: @Philippe Worth noticing that they wont run in parallel. One will run just after the other.

Comment: @lukas I would like to say you won't be able to run any other git command in this repository once you start your script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beside making other commands fail if executed too often, then main drawback of a regular fetch is on the `push --force-with-lease`.

I have documented as much in "[`push --force-with-lease` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726130/6309)"

> `--force-with-lease` or `--force-with-lease=<refname>` interacts very badly with anything that implicitly runs `git fetch` on the remote to be pushed to in the background, e.g. `git fetch origin` on your repository in a cronjob.
>
> The protection it offers over `--force` is ensuring that subsequent changes your work wasn't based on aren't clobbered, but this is trivially defeated if some background process is updating refs in the background.