# When should I use "git push --force-if-includes"

Tags: git, git-push

When I want to force push, I nearly always use `--force-with-lease`. Today I upgraded to Git 2.30 and discovered a new option: `--force-if-includes`.

After reading the [updated documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), it's still not entirely clear to me under which circumstances I would use `--force-if-includes` instead of `--force-with-lease` like I usually do.

Comment: Maybe this flag should be renamed to "--force-if-local-head-matches-remote-head", because that's really what I would like. I usually run `git push --force-with-lease master:refs/heads/master`. I'm intending to re-write commit A to commit Ax. If the remote commit is NO LONGER A, then I want to abort. Maybe the whole thing could be revised to: `git push --force --replace-sha=a1s2d3f`

Comment: Actually damn. I am re-reading the answer below from @torek and realized I am actually totally missing the point of --force-if-includes. `git push --force-with-lease origin main` already does what I am saying should be done...

Comment: The caveat is around `git fetch` - read torek's answer below.

Comment: This one explains well: https://delicious-insights.com/en/posts/git-push-with-lease/

Answer (score 104, accepted):

## TL;DR

The new-in-Git-2.30 `--force-if-includes` does nothing *unless* you *also* include `--force-with-lease`.  If you *do* use `--force-with-lease`, that alone *can suffice*.  I'm not convinced of the utility of `--force-if-includes` myself and would personally use a multi-step process:

```
git fetch <remote>         # get commit(s) from remote
git show <remote>/<name>   # inspect their most recent commit
                           # to make sure it's what we think
                           # it is, so that we're sure of what
                           # we're tossing *from* their Git repo
```

Then, if all goes well above:

```
git push --force-with-lease <remote> <name>
```

However, if you develop your own preference, that's fine too: just remember that `--force-if-includes` means your Git, doing the force-with-lease push, checks that you have seen their latest commit at least once with an earlier `git fetch`.  This means you must pay close attention to what `git fetch` fetches (which is why I would just do a fetch-and-inspect, and then not bother with the new flag anyway).

If you're not using `--force` or `--force-with-lease` you *definitely* don't need the new flag.  Since most `git push` operations don't need `--force` in the first place, you can skip all the fancy stuff and just use a regular (non-forced) push without doing the careful inspection.

## Long

The `--force-if-includes` option is, as you've noted, new.  If you've never needed it before, you don't need it now.  So the shortest answer to "when should I use this" would be "never".  The *recommended* answer is (or will be once it's proven?) *always*.  (I'm not yet convinced one way or the other, myself.)

A blanket "always" or "never" is not very useful though.  Let's look at where you might want to use it.  It is, strictly speaking, never *necessary* because all it does is modify `--force-with-lease` slightly.  So we already have `--force-with-lease` in effect, if `--force-if-includes` is going to be used.<sup>1</sup>  Before we look at `--force-with-includes` we should cover how `--force-with-lease` actually works.  What *problem* are we trying to solve?  What are our "use cases" or "user stories" or whatever the latest buzzwords might be when someone is reading this later?

(Note: if you're already familiar with all of this, you can search for the next force-if-includes string to skip the next few sections, or just jump to the bottom and then scroll up to the section header.)

The fundamental problem we have here is one of *atomicity*.  Git is, in the end, mostly—or at least significantly—a database, and any good database has four properties for which we have the mnemonic [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID): Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, and Durability.  Git doesn't exactly achieve any or all of these on its own: for instance, for the Durability property, it relies (at least partly) on the OS to provide it.  But three of these—the C, I, and D ones—are local within a Git repository in the first place: if your computer crashes, *your* copy of the database may or may not be intact, recoverable, or whatever, depending on the state of your own hardware and OS.

Git is not, however, just a local database.  It's a *distributed* one, distributed via replication, and its unit of atomicity—the commit—is spread out across multiple replications of the database.  When we make a new commit locally, we can send it to some other copy or copies of the database, using `git push`.  Those copies will try to provide their own ACID behavior, locally on *those* computers.  But we'd like to preserve atomicity *during the push itself*.

We can get this in several ways.  One way is to start with the idea that every commit has a globally (or universally) unique identifier: a GUID or UUID.<sup>2</sup>  (I'll use the UUID form here.)  I can safely give you a new commit I've made as long as we both agree that it gets the UUID I gave it, that you didn't have.

But, while Git does use these UUIDs to *find* the commits, Git also needs to have a *name* for the commit—well, for the *last* commit in some chain.  This guarantees that whoever is using the repository has a way to find the commit: the name finds the *last* one in some chain, from which we find all the earlier ones in the same chain.

If we both use the same *name*, we have a problem.  Let's say we're using the name `main` to find commit `b789abc`, and they're using it to find the commit `a123456`.

The solution we use with `git fetch` here is simple: we assign a name to their Git repository, e.g., `origin`.  Then, when we get some new commit(s) from them, we take *their* name—the one that finds the last of these commits in some chain, that is—and *rename* it.  If they used the name `main` to find that tip commit, we rename that to `origin/main`.  We create or update our own `origin/main` to remember *their* commits, and it does not mess with our own `main`.

But, when we're going the other way—pushing our commits to them—Git doesn't apply this idea.  Instead, we ask them to update their `main` directly.  We hand over commit `b789abc` for instance, and then ask them to set *their* `main` to `b789abc`.  What they do, to make sure that they don't *lose* their `a123456` commit, is make sure that `a123456` is part of the *history* of our commit `b789abc`:

```
  ... <-a123456 <-b789abc   <--main
```

Since our `main` points to `b789abc`, and `b789abc` has `a123456` as its parent, then having *them* update *their* `main` to point to `b789abc` is "safe".  For this to really be safe, *they* have to atomically replace their `main`, but we just leave that up to them.

This method of *adding* commits to some remote Git repository works fine.  What *doesn't* work is the case where we'd like to *remove* their `a123456`.  We find there is something wrong or bad with `a123456`.  Instead of making a simple correction, `b789abc`, that *adds on* to the branch, we make our `b789abc` so that it *bypasses* the bad commit:

```
... <-something <-a123456   <--main
```

becomes:

```
... <-something <-b789abc   <--main
               \
                a123456   ??? [no name, hence abandoned]
```

We then try to send this commit to them, and they reject our attempt with the gripe that it's not a "fast-forward".  We add `--force` to tell them to do the replacement anyway, and—if we have appropriate permissions<sup>3</sup>—their Git obeys.  This effectively *drops* the bad commit from their clone, just as we dropped it from ours.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>As the documentation you linked notes, `--force-if-includes` *without* `--force-with-lease` is just ignored.  That is, `--force-if-includes` doesn't turn *on* `--force-with-lease` *for* you: you have to specify both.

<sup>2</sup>These are the *hash IDs*, and they need to be unique across all Gits that will ever meet and share IDs, but not across two Gits that never meet.  There, we can safely have what I call "doppelgängers": commits or other internal objects with the same hash ID, but different content.  Still, it's best to just make them truly unique.

<sup>3</sup>Git as it is, "out of the box", does not have this kind of permissions checking, but hosting providers like GitHub and Bitbucket add it, as part of their value-adding thing to convince us to use their hosting systems.

<sup>4</sup>The un-find-able commit doesn't actually *go away* right away.  Instead, Git leaves this for a later housekeeping `git gc` operation.  Also, dropping a commit from some name may still leave that commit reachable from other names, or via log entries that Git keeps for each name.  If so, the commit will stick around longer, perhaps even forever.

---

#### So far so good, but ...

The concept of a force-push is fine as far as it goes, but that's not far enough.  Suppose we have a repository, hosted somewhere (GitHub or whatever), that receives `git push` requests.  Suppose further that *we are not the only person / group doing pushes*.

We `git push` some new commit, then discover it's bad and want to replace it with a new and improved commit immediately, so we take a few seconds or minutes—however long it takes to make the new improved commit—and get that in place and run `git push --force`.  For concreteness, let's say this whole thing takes us one minute, or 60 seconds.

That's sixty seconds during which *someone else* might:<sup>5</sup>

- fetch our bad commit from the hosting system;
- add a new commit of their own; and
- `git push` the result.

So at this point, we *think* the hosting system has:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

where commit `H` is bad and needs replacement with our new-and-improved `H'`.  But in fact, they now have:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- main
```

where commit `I` is from this other faster committer.  Meanwhile, we now have, in *our* repository, the sequence:

```
...--F--G--H'  <-- main
         \
          H   ???
```

where `H` is our bad commit, that we're about to replace.  We now run `git push --force` and since we are allowed to force-push, the hosting provider Git accepts our new `H'` as the last commit in *their* `main`, so that *they* now have:

```
...--F--G--H'  <-- main
         \
          H--I   ???
```

The effect is that our `git push --force` removed not only our bad `H`, but their (presumably still good, or at least, wanted) `I`.

---

<sup>5</sup>They might do this by rebasing a commit they'd already made, after finding their own `git push` blocked because they had based their commit on `G` originally.  Their rebase automatically copied their new commit to the one we're calling `I` here, with no merge conflicts, enabling them to run `git push` in fewer seconds than it took us to make our fixed-up commit `H'`.

---

#### Enter `--force-with-lease`

The `--force-with-lease` option, which internally Git calls a "compare and swap", allows us to send a commit to some other Git, and then *have them check* that their branch name—whatever it is—contains the hash ID that we think it contains.

Let's add, to our drawing of our own repository, the `origin/*` names.  Since we sent commit `H` to the hosting provider earlier, and they took it, we actually have *this* in our repository:

```
...--F--G--H'  <-- main
         \
          H   <-- origin/main
```

When we use `git push --force-with-lease`, we have the option of controlling this `--force-with-lease` completely and exactly.  The complete syntax for doing this is:

```
git push --force-with-lease=refs/heads/main:<hash-of-H> origin <hash-of-H'>:refs/heads/main
```

That is, we'll:

- send to `origin` commits ending with the one found via hash ID `H'`;
- ask them to update their name `refs/heads/main` (their `main` branch); and
- ask them to force this update, but *only* if their `refs/heads/main` currently has in it the hash ID of commit `H`.

This gives us a chance to catch the case where some commit `I` has been added to their `main`.  They, using the `--force-with-lease=refs/heads/main:<hash>` part, *check* their `refs/heads/main`.  If it's not the given `<hash>`, they refuse the entire transaction, keeping their database intact: they retain commits `I` and `H`, and drop our new commit `H'` on the floor.<sup>6</sup>

The overall transaction—the forced-with-lease update of their `main`—has locking inserted so that if someone else is attempting to push some commit (perhaps `I`) now, the someone-else gets held off until we finish—fail or succeed—with our `--force-with-lease` operation.

We usually don't spell all this out, though.  Usually we would just run:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin main
```

Here, `main` provides both the hash ID of the last commit we want sent—`H'`—and the ref-name we want them to update (`refs/heads/main`, based on the fact that our `main` is a branch name).  The `--force-with-lease` has no `=` part so Git fills in the rest: the ref name is the one we want them to update—`refs/heads/main`—and the expected commit is the one in our corresponding *remote-tracking name*, i.e., the one in our own `refs/remotes/origin/main`.

This all comes out the same: our `origin/main` provides the `H` hash, and our `main` provides the `H'` hash and all the other names.  It's shorter and does the trick.

---

<sup>6</sup>This depends on their Git having the "quarantine" feature in it, but anyone who has force-with-lease has this feature, I think.  The quarantine feature dates back quite a while.  Really-old versions of Git that lack the quarantine feature can leave the pushed commits around until a `git gc` collects them, even if they've never been incorporated.

---

#### This finally brings us to `--force-if-includes`

The example use case with `--force-with-lease` above shows how we replace a bad commit *we made*, when *we figured that out ourselves*.  All we did was replace it and push.  But this isn't how people always work.

Suppose we make a bad commit, exactly as before.  We wind up in this situation in our own local repository:

```
...--F--G--H'  <-- main
         \
          H   <-- origin/main
```

But now we run `git fetch origin`.  Perhaps we're trying to be conscientious; perhaps we're under stress and making mistakes.  Whatever is going on, we now get:

```
...--F--G--H'  <-- main
         \
          H--I   <-- origin/main
```

in our own repository.

If we use `git push --force-with-lease=main:<hash-of-H> origin main`, the push will fail—like it *should*—because we explicitly state that we expect origin's `main` to contain hash ID `H`.  As we can see from our `git fetch`, though, it actually has hash ID `I`.  If we use the simpler:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin main
```

we'll ask the hosting-provider Git to swap out their `main` for commit `H'` if they have commit `I` as their last commit.  Which, as we can see, they did: we got commit `I` into our repository.  We just *forgot to put it in.*

So, our force-with-lease works and we wipe out commit `I` over on `origin`, all because we ran `git fetch` and forgot to check the result.  The `--force-if-includes` option is *intended* to catch these cases.

How it actually works is that it depends on Git's reflogs.  It scans your own reflog for your `main` branch, and picks out commit `H` rather than `I`, to be used as the hash ID in `--force-with-lease`.  This is similar to the fork-point mode for `git rebase` (though that one uses your remote-tracking reflog).  I'm not 100% convinced, myself, that this `--force-if-includes` option is going to work in all cases: `--fork-point` does not, for instance.  But it does work in *most* cases, and I suspect `--force-if-includes` will too.

So, you can try it out by using it for all `--force-with-lease` pushes.  All it does is use a different algorithm—one the Git folks are *hoping* will be more reliable, given the way humans are—to pick the hash ID for the atomic "swap out your branch name if this matches" operation that `--force-with-lease` uses.  You can do this manually by providing the `=<refname>:<hash>` part of `--force-with-lease`, but the goal is to do it automatically, in a safer way than the current automatic way.

Comment: In your example, suppose I have fetched commit `I`, checked it out in my branch, and I don't like it, so I reset --hard back to `H` and force push it out. My `origin/main` now is at `H`, but my reflog already has `I` in it. Now I add a new commit `J` locally, and meanwhile, my co-worker who really liked `I` noticed it was gone and pushes it back out. I haven't fetched yet, and if I push `J` with `--force-with-lease` without args I expect it will fail, which is good. But if I do `--force-if-includes` it might work, because I've been at commit `I` already? (Contrived but possible, I think...)

Comment: I haven't delved into the actual code for `--force-if-includes`, which I'd need to do, to figure out how to trick it. But that does seem like a likely possibility.

Comment: It may be a trade off. I'll probably ending up staying with `--force-with-lease`. But I've heard of people who have fetch running automatically in the background on a schedule on their machine. I suppose for them, `--force-if-includes` is much better than `--force-with-lease`. Perhaps they were the ones that *pushed* for this feature to begin with. ;)

Comment: @TTT: I think that's likely, especially because there's some other new upcoming stuff to make auto-background-fetching more functional. Also: I see what you did there :-)

Comment: @torek Do you know of a shorter syntax for the "fully explicit" usage of `--force-with-lease`? Maybe some of these complexities would be better handled in a pre-push hook?

Comment: @DevinRhode: There isn't any shorter syntax (unfortunate IMO; `-f` should really be short for the safer one, except that it can't be due to backwards compatibility). A pre-push hook can't guarantee atomicity either: it will depend on what the other side implements.

Comment: @torek Could you put a very short summary of recommended approaches at the top of your answer? I'd propose something like: "Using git push --force-with-lease origin main works quite well in most situations. However, git push --force-with-lease --force-if-includes origin main is slightly safer. However, the safest approach is to use: git push --force-with-lease=refs/heads/main:<expected-remote-sha> origin main:refs/heads/main"

Comment: It's almost like we'd want to create such an alias: `git safe-force-push`. It will run `git fetch origin main`, and then ask you to confirm the latest commit on main is what you were expecting. Alternatively, git could implement something like `git push --force --replace-sha=a1s2d3f`. Running `git safe-push --replace-sha=a1s2d3f` would skip the prompt.

Comment: @DevinRhode: in fact, `--force-with-lease` actually allows you to provide all the inputs: "I expect refspec <name> to equal <hash1>; if so, force-replace it with <hash2>". This is functionally equivalent to machine language "compare and swap" instructions, and inside Git is called "compare and swap"...

Comment: Anyway, I did attempt to add a shorter version, though it's still not all that short.

Comment: Something that can annoy me sometimes, vscode will run git fetch at a regular interval in the background. So I'm certain this --force-if-includes was intended to help users like myself.

Comment: The TLDR version is really nice

Comment: I'd like to add a "pedantic" option near the top, after your `git push --force-with-lease <remote> <name>` example. In monorepos with lots of push activity going on, it may help.

Comment: Would `git push --force-with-lease=refs/heads/main:<hash-of-H> origin <hash-of-H'>:refs/heads/main` be a valid "pedantic" example?

Comment: Er, I think this would be a more appropriate "pedantic" example: `git push --force-with-lease=refs/heads/main:<expected-remote-sha> origin main`. Idk why but I always have this issue with force pushing where specifying the full local:remote refspec solves the issue. Doing normal `git push --force` usually shows me "Everything up to date" or "Already up to date"

Comment: @DevinRhode: I've found that humans (including myself) really hate to use raw hash IDs. Even with cut-and-paste, it's too easy to drop a character or whatever - they're just *hard* to get right! So I, at least, find it's better to run `git fetch` and look at the result. But whatever works for you, obvious works for you... 

Comment: I really appreciate hashing through the details with you @torek! I added my own answer below.

Answer (score 12):

My ultimate safest solution to avoid accidentally overwritten other dev's commit goes like this, use 2 options at the same time. `git config --global alias.pushf 'push --force-with-lease --force-if-includes'`

```
[alias]

    pushf = push --force-with-lease --force-if-includes
```

> Alternatively, specifying `--force-if-includes` as an ancillary option along with `--force-with-lease[=<refname>]` (i.e., without saying what exact commit the ref on the remote side must be pointing at, or which refs on the remote side are being protected) at the time of "push" will verify if updates from the remote-tracking refs that may have been implicitly updated in the background are integrated locally before allowing a forced update.

Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: While the intricacies of --force-if-includes are incredibly hard to understand, now that I fully understand @torek's answer above, I am pretty sure this is not the "ultimate" or "safest" way to force push. The ultimate/safest way would be to explicitly specify all sha's like so: `git push --force-with-lease=refs/heads/main:<hash-of-H> origin <hash-of-H'>:refs/heads/main`

Comment: I suppose “always use it (when force-pushing)” is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 11):

If you're always using `--force-with-lease` as-is instead of `--force` and looking for some quick info, start using `--force-with-lease --force-with-includes` instead as it is marginally safer.

If I can have your attention for a little longer then read on. ***If you `git fetch` before `git push --force-with-lease` you are essentially just force pushing with no safety.*** Adding `--force-if-includes` will use the reflog in addition to the remote tracking branch to help protect against this sort of thing because performing a fetch seems pretty innocuous and might even happen in the back ground.

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), ***bold italics*** on my commentary, **bold** on the emphasis.

> ```
> --[no-]force-with-lease
> --force-with-lease=<refname>
> --force-with-lease=<refname>:<expect>
> ```
>
> Usually, "git push" refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it.
>
> This option overrides this restriction if the current value of the remote ref is the expected value. "git push" fails otherwise.
>
> [...]
>
> Alternatively, specifying `--force-if-includes` as an ancillary option along with `--force-with-lease[=<refname>]` ***(this is what we are doing when we do `--force-with-lease`)*** (i.e., without saying what exact commit the ref on the remote side must be pointing at, or which refs on the remote side are being protected) at the time of "push" **will verify if updates from the remote-tracking refs that may have been implicitly updated in the background are integrated locally before allowing a forced update.**

What that means is if you're force (with lease) pushing your `blah` branch to `origin` and your `origin/blah` branch (the remote tracking branch) is different than the server's `blah` branch it stops you. ***This implies someone made a change you didn't know about.***

There are better ways to use `--force-with-lease` but let's be honest, we're just looking for something quick and safe. If you want to learn about them go check out the docs. Using `--force-if-includes` checks your reflog in addition to the remote tracking branch to make sure there's no changes you missed.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually the safest possible way to force push, and my personal recommendation:

```bash
git push --force-with-lease=refs/heads/main:<expected-remote-sha> origin main
```

This makes `--force-if-includes` irrelevant, because you are telling git point blank what remote sha you expect to replace. I don't know of any way this could be made any safer.

<sub>*Of course, once you aren't specifying a full explicit sha, it becomes less safe.


**If you have new commits being pushed every second in some huge monorepo, then you're basically in a race against other developers, you probably shouldn't be force pushing.


***Credit to @torek for the ****awesome**** explanations!</sub>

Comment: People may be curious why some developers on this page care about safer force pushing. Here's why I care about it: I often force push to my own feature branches. This can cause problems for collaboration. If others want to push changes to my branch, I may accidentally clobber them. By using this fully explicit force push syntax, I can be sure that I am not clobbering any potential change they make.

Comment: This can eliminate the boundary between code author and code reviewer. If reviewers are free to push changes to a PR branch, effectively they are also authors. The original author and reviewer can discuss the original reviewers new change, as if they are on the same side of the fence. However, the boundary still exists somewhat, generally authors are not allowed to approve their own code..

Comment: I think this "approval" issue could be improved by doing this: All PRs are automatically clear for approval after 4-5 core working hours pass, unless a reviewer "disapproves" it.

Comment: I'm curious how you determine what `<expected-remote-sha>` is? (Disclaimer: this is a leading question...)

Comment: If pushing to master, I'd open github.com and look at recent PRs, look at commits on master, etc. If pushing to my feature branch, I might consult git reflog, use the "Git Graph" vscode extension (a reflog gui), or look at sha's on my github Pull Request page. Of course, if a commit on my PR branch is not from me, or is unfamiliar, I'll pause and reconsider force pushing my current branch.

Comment: I'd likely also use `git fetch origin && git log -1 origin/<branch>`

Comment: If the sha is unfamiliar, again, I may inspect the sha's, comment on some recently merged PRs, communicate elsewhere, etc. I may run some sort of git pull/rebase/cherry-pick operation before force pushing to avoid clobbering other work.

Comment: Right. I asked because I've never seen the benefit of explicitly specifying the expected hash with `--force-with-lease`. I think fetching and looking at `origin/<branch>` is probably the norm, and `--force-with-lease` protects against looking but not having fetched recently enough. If you always look at `origin/<branch>` first, then I don't think you need to explicitly specify the commit SHA since it's already using that. If for some reason you know you won't fetch, and you will use the remote repo UI to determine the commit, then I suppose explicitly providing it might help.

Comment: That being said, even though *I* probably wouldn't ever explicitly specify the hash, this is an easy upvote because *if* you make the extra effort to do that, then I fully agree with: "This makes --force-if-includes irrelevant".

Answer (score 2):

## Make force push safer

You may use git exclusively through the cli, but, some editors (like vscode), it will automatically run `git fetch` every 2 minutes in the background, and show you if there are new commits to pull down.

If you want safer force pushing, you'll need to disable auto-fetching inside your editor.

First, it's a good idea to force push through the gui, because it uses very explicit syntax:

[image: vscode git gui extension push/pull dropdown menu "force push" option]

vscode runs this under-the-hood:

```bash
git push --force-with-lease origin feature/foo:feature/foo
```

You can influence this call with the git config option `push.useForceIfIncludes`:

```
[push]
  useForceIfIncludes = true
```

You can combine this with disabling auto-fetching in vscode:

```json
"git.autofetch": false,
```

This would then cause force pushes through vscode's gui menu to fail unless you explicitly run `git fetch` or `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` before hand.

<sub>A gui could make this even safer, doing things like:

 - show the diff between your local branch and the remote branch

 - show diff of log, allowing you to see which shas/commits will be obliterated, and what they will be replaced with

 - tell you if force push is even necessary

 - implement *even safer* checks</sub>