# How to remove a removed commit from a feature branch based of develop?

Tags: git, gitlab

So we have a `develop` branch which we base our feature branches from.

Two days ago someone pushed a bad commit to `develop`, but I based my feature branch of it and already have few commits pushed into it. They removed the unnecessary commit from the `develop` branch but it still stays in my feature branch commits. It looks something like this:

```
   bad commit
       \
o---o---X develop
         \
          X---o---o---o feature
           \
        bad commit
```

What I need to do is to remove the commit that I based my branch of and instead rebase to the commit before it. Do i use `git rebase --i` or `git rebase --onto`, I'm not really sure. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will need to `git rebase` your banch on the updated `develop` branch. When presented with the pick list you will need to delete the bad commit.

Comment: Either `git rebase -i` or `git rebase --onto` can do the job; so can a plain `git rebase` when using the fork point mode. There's no single right answer: just use one that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a single commit with commit ID (hash) `X` from branch `feature`:

```
git rebase X feature --onto X~1
```

**Side Note:** what just happened to you is the reason force pushing a shared branch is frowned upon. (Someone force pushed `develop` to create this issue.) The usual course of action when you have a bad commit *on a shared branch* is to revert that commit instead of rewriting and force pushing. Had it been reverted, you could have updated your branch the same way you always do, perhaps:

```
git fetch
# then either:
git rebase origin/develop
# or
git merge origin/develop
```

Comment: That is the answer, thanks! And your side note was the exact case what happened.
Just to add to your answer - after runing the rebase a force push should be done - ``git push origin feature -f``

Comment: @MindPhuq Yes, you must force push after rebasing an already pushed branch. Btw, when force pushing, I (generally) would suggest the safer options of `--force-with-lease` or `--force-if-includes`, or [both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65837109/184546).