# Merging main branch into my feature branch

Tags: git, github

I created a feature branch from main branch then opened a pr from feature branch to main branch then after a while squash merged main branch into my feature branch to keep it up to date
Now i have changes from main branch as additions in the pr and they also exist in my feature branch
How can i display in the pr only the changes from feature branch that aren't on main branch?

I tried closing the pr then reopening it but still shows me changes that i didn't make

Comment: You probably want to revert that squash merge. Generally, I recommend updating a feature branch by rebasing it on the tip of the base branch.

Answer (score 3):

When prepping for merging a personal feature branch into `main`, if you wish to update your feature branch with the latest changes from `main`, you generally should do one of the following:

1. Rebase your branch onto the latest `main` and then force push<sup>2</sup> your feature branch to update the PR.
2. If there is a reason that you shouldn't do #1, (for example if your feature branch is *not* a true feature branch and is instead a shared branch), then you should merge `main` into your feature branch using a regular merge.

Squash merge should not be used for updating a feature branch with the target branch of a PR.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some exceptions to this rule, such as when the target branch is a shared branch that gets periodically reset, such as the `next` branch in [gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows). In that case squash merge is helpful to make a future interactive rebase easier, when promoting the feature branch to another branch such as `main` in a future PR.

<sup>2</sup> Use your favorite flavor of force pushing. I tend to prefer `--force-with-lease`, though nowadays some prefer using: `--force-with-lease --force-if-includes`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65837109/184546) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted the merge of main into my feature branch and the problem was solved
I'll try to rebase when updating my branch.