# How to completely ignore pushed commits and merged with master branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

After pushing some commits on the `dev` branch, and merging them with `master` branch. I want to back to 4 commits ago. I can do that using `git reset --hard <hash-id>` (which `hash-id` is the 4th previous commits)

but when I want to push it again on the `dev` branch, it says "do a `git pull` first" because news changes exits on the remote `dev` branch.

To fix the problem, I run the following commands:

```
git reset --hard <hash-id>
git clean -d -f
git push -f origin dev
```

Now the `dev` branch is what I want, but when I want to merge it with the `master` branch it says "no changes found".

It is very strange, because the code base is different in branch `dev` and `master`, but it says that no changes were found. How can I make the dev branch and master the same content?

Comment: Is your local `master` branch up to date? Try running `git checkout master; git pull` first, and then re-try the merge.

Comment: I think the wording of merge "with" is confusing. I believe @larsks's comment is interpreting "merge with" as merging `master` into `dev`, though I think what you mean here is you are merging `dev` into `master`. It's better to say "into" instead of "with" so it's obvious which is the source and target branch for the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you cannot *remove* commits using merge, and you already merged those 4 commits that used to be on `dev` into `master`. If you want them gone from `master` also you'll need to do a hard reset of `master` to before the merge of `dev`, and then force push `master` as well. (This assumes you are OK with force pushing `master`; see the Side Note below for an alternative.)

The reason you see "no changes found" when merging `dev` into `master`, is because Git looks at the commit IDs to see which commit IDs are on `dev` that are not on `master`. Whether you reset dev back 1 commit, or 100 commits you'd still get that same message because there aren't any *new* commits on `dev` that aren't already on `master`.

**Side Note:** An alternative way to "undo" those 4 commits, instead of resetting backwards like you did, is to use revert. If the merge of `dev` into `master` created a merge commit on `master`, then you can simply revert that merge commit on `master` and it will undo the changes brought in by those 4 commits. Whether you should reset or revert is usually dependent on whether the branch is shared or not. If other people are using the `master` branch then resetting and force pushing it could mess them up, so revert would be preferred.

**Another Side Note:** You also mentioned:

> How can I make the dev branch and master the same content?

Doing as mentioned above will achieve your goal, however if by "same content" you also mean that `dev` and `master` should point to the same commit, then your reset command of `master` could simply be:

```
git switch master # checkout master
git reset --hard dev # point master to what dev is pointing to
git push --force-with-lease # this is safer than just --force
```

Comment: I tired your solution, almost all went well, but in the last step (pushing on the `main` branch), I got this error because of being a protected branch https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Jkp.jpg .. any idea?

Comment: @MartinAJ That makes sense. Like I mentioned in the side note, rewriting shared branches can mess other people up, so it's a good idea to prevent force pushing of shared branches. In that case your options are to revert instead of resetting, or to get temporary permission to force push from an admin, or ask an admin to do the reset and force push it. Also, usually when you force push a shared branch you'll want to let everyone know in case they have already started work based on the commits you are removing.

Comment: Why is `force-with-lease` safer than `force`?

Comment: @oldergod It depends on your workflow.  `--force` will blow away the remote branch and repoint it to what you tell it, without checking anything. `--force-with-lease` checks to see if there are new commits on the remote since your last fetch. If you blindly fetch all the time (or use pull regularly), or setup some sort of process that fetches regularly behind the scenes, then `--force-with-lease` won't be any safer. But if you only `git fetch` on purpose when you are ready to look at what you get, then `--force-with-lease` is marginally safer.

Comment: @oldergod there's a (relatively) new option as well, `--force-if-includes` which adds additional checks to `--force-with-lease`. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65837109/184546)