# Merge conflict with myself

Tags: git, merge, git-commit

I had a merge conflict a while ago and had the suspicion, that it was with myself. Right now I had the same problem again and this time I'm certain, that I'm responsible for the conflict.

Yesterday I made some changes to my branch `commit`ed the changes and `push`ed them. This was the first and so far only commit to the branch (local, as well as remote).

Today I made some more changes (in the same files obviously), added the changes and commited them with `commit --amend`and tried to `push` them.

This is were I had a merge conflict: `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

I fixed the changes, added, commited and pushed them. All fine now.

But I want to learn from my mistakes. **What IS the mistake?** (I assume it has something to do with using `git commit --amend`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`amend` -- changes history.

Initial state

```
Origin: A
Local:  A
```

Then you commited and pushed

```
Origin: A - B
Local:  A - B
```

Then you commited with amend

```
Origin: A - B
Local:  A - C // local commit B replaced by new commit C
```

Then you tried to push and got message, that you need to pull before. Commit C contains changes from B but it is a different commit. And there for you have conflict after pull.

Answer (score 4):

First, this:

> ```
> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
> ```

is *not* a merge conflict.  A merge conflict is something more specific.  It occurs when a *three-way merge* is trying to combine two different sets of changes, but the changes overlap.  You are running `git push`, which *does not merge anything*.

The opposite of `git push` is *not* `git pull`.  The `git pull` command is a convenience command that runs *two* Git commands for you, in sequence.  The first command is `git fetch`—which *is* the opposite of `git push`, or at least, as close as one can get.  The *second* command that `git pull` runs is normally `git merge`, which *can* result in a merge conflict.  Or, you can direct Git to run `git rebase` second instead; and `git rebase` can also result in a merge conflict.

#### Some key facts to just memorize

This can get very confusing, and to use Git well, it's important to learn how Git actually does all of these things, because Git tends to let the raw implementation show through.  So as a base overview, keep in mind the following:

- What matters most, most of the time, is *commits*.
- Every commit has a single "true name", which is its hash ID.  Hash IDs are those big ugly 40-character things like `face0ff` (but longer).  No two different commits ever have the same ID, and the ID is determined entirely by the *contents* of the commit.
- The *contents* of a commit are a little bit detailed but not too long—to see one in its entirety, run `git cat-file -p HEAD`, which just prints it out—but the main important thing to remember is that the contents include:

  - the *parent commit*, which is again one of those hashes;
  - the *commit message* (which `--amend` seems to let you edit); and
  - the *source tree* that you commit, i.e., whatever you have `git add`-ed.

  When you use `git commit --amend`, this *seems* to change the commit, but it doesn't.  It can't!  The commit's ID is determined by its contents.  If you change the contents, you get a new and therefore *different* commit.
- Because commits have their parent IDs inside them, Git (and you) can draw a *chain* of commits, starting from the more recent ones and working backwards.  Git runs everything backwards: we like to think of branches as going forwards.  If we have a time line of commits, where we make commit `A`, then `B`, then `C`, and so on, we'd expect them to go "A then B then C":

  ```
  A -> B -> C
  ```

  but Git does them backwards, so they're actually:

  ```
  A <- B <- C
  ```
- Therefore, a *branch name* just points to the *tip-most* commit.  This is why Git keeps talking about "the tip of your branch".
- And, that means we want to draw our graphs like this:

  ```
  A--B--C   <-- branch
  ```

  The name `branch` points to the *latest* commit, `C`.  Git then goes backwards, from `C` to `B` to `A`.  Most of the time we don't have to worry about that part, but we do need to remember that the *name* just points to the tip commit.

#### This leads to the way branches grow

Branch names point to branch-tips.  Suppose you have one of those chains:

```
A--B--C   <-- branch
```

Now you make a new commit `D`.  What Git does is make `D` with its parent being `C`, then make `branch` point to `D`.  We can draw that now:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- branch
```

What `git commit --amend` does is now very simple to see.  Instead of tacking `D` onto the *end* by making `D` point back to `C`, it makes `D` point back to `B` (i.e., `C`'s parent).  Then it shoves `C` aside by making `branch` point to `D`:

```
     C
    /
A--B--D   <-- branch
```

#### Now we can see what `git push` does as well

When you run `git push`, your Git calls up some other Git and has a little conversation.  Your Git tells their Git about *your* commits.  Their Git tells your Git about *their* commits.  Your Git then sends their Git some of your commits—whichever ones you have, that they don't, that you've asked your Git to send.

Suppose they already have `A--B--C` and you have `A--B--D`.  By asking your Git to `git push branch`, you get your Git to send them your `D` (it would send your `A` and `B` too, but they already have those; again, these are all done by those big ugly hash IDs, rather than simple one-letter names, but the idea is the same).

Then comes the last part, which is where the problem is.  Your Git asks their Git to set *their* `branch` to point to the same commit as your `branch`.  That is, you ask them to set *their* `branch` to point to `D`.

Your `D` points back to `B`, not to `C`.  If they were to set *their* `branch` to point to the new shared `D`, they would "lose" their `C`.

Of course, because of your `amend`, you *want* them to "lose" their `C`, just like you did when your Git shoved it aside.  So you can use `--force`.  The force flag changes your Git's polite request—"please, if you will, change your `branch` to point to `D`—into a command: "set your `branch` to point to `D` right now!"  They can still refuse, but generally they will obey.

If that *only* loses `C`, that's fine: that's what you wanted.  But if their Git is one others also push to, perhaps a third person, with a third Git repository, has written a commit `E` and pushed it to their Git, so that they actually have `A--B--C--E`.  If you send them your `D`, which points back to `B`, and get them to set their `branch` to point to your `D`, they will lose the `C--E` *chain*, not just the `C` commit.

#### This is why (and when) amending is bad

If you amend a commit you have already shared, it's possible that someone else has built on it.  If you now "take it away", you may create problems for this someone-else.

On the other hand, if you have never shared the commit, or if the other Git is your own private repository, or if you and all third-parties *agree in advance* that this sort of "taking away" is normal and expected, you won't have a problem here.

Otherwise—if "taking away" is bad—then when the other Git has a commit, you should make sure that whatever new commits you push merely *add to* their commits.  You can do this by merging, or by rebasing, and that's where `git merge` or `git rebase` come in.  Not exactly coincidentally, these two commands are the second half of `git pull`—but let's leave that for another time.

Answer (score 1):

> What IS the mistake? (I assume it has something to do with using git commit --amend)

Yes, it has to do with using `git commit --amend`. By amending commits, you have overwritten your `git history` ( by changing commit's SHA1).  `Amend` is fine as long as you haven't published your changes(pushed to some remote branch), but once you do, you really shouldn't be mucking around with the history, because if someone already got your changes, then when they try to pull again, it might fail (Tip: instead of amending a commit, you should just make a new commit with the changes ).

Now, git will refuse to update the remote branch with your branch (having amend public commit) because your branch's head commit is not a `direct descendant` of the current head commit of the branch that you are pushing to.

If you want to replace the remote history by your (amended) local one, you will need to [force push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push/12610763#12610763).
If you don't, Git will refuse the push, and ask you to pull (which in this case is not helpful, as you would merge with identical content but different commit messages).

However, [git push --force-with-lease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166713/git-how-to-ignore-fast-forward-and-revert-origin-branch-to-earlier-commit/18505634#18505634) is much safer. Follow up the link to know more about it.

> if something happens at 'origin' to the branch you are forcing or deleting since you fetched to inspect it, you may end up losing other people's work.
>
> Somebody who is unaware of the decision to rewind and rebuild the branch may attempt to push to the branch between the time you fetched to rebase it and the time you pushed to replace it with the result of the rebasing.
>
> We can make these pushes safer by optionally allowing the user to tell "git push" this:
>
> **I am forcing/deleting, based on the assumption that the value of 'branch' is still at this object.
> If that assumption no longer holds, i.e. if something happened to the branch since I started preparing for this push, please do not proceed and fail this push.**

Comment: Thank you. This was also very helpful.