# git checkout from remote

Tags: git

I have been reading other questions on stack overflow but nothing simply explains what I need. I am pushing to a remote repo with one other collaborator. I want to check out a past commit from a few weeks ago. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git checkout -b <branch_name> <sha1>
```

(this will create a new branch and checkout at that particular commit that you want)

If you just want to reset current branch to it:

```
git reset --hard <sha1>
```

Update on sha1:

What I meant by Sha1 is this long hash that is associated with each commit and identifies it. You can easily find it by doing a `git log`

Sample git log output:

```
commit 10a45e0f0680b8fd493ed0264fe24be2648af1b3
Author: manojlds <manojlds@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Oct 13 19:04:23 2011 -0600

    some other commit
```

`10a45e0f0680b8fd493ed0264fe24be2648af1b3` is the sha1 hash.

Comment: +1 (more concise, and the `git reset` can also help). I'll keep mine because I think it is important to illustrate the issue of DETACHED HEAD when being tempted to checkout a SHA1 without creating a branch.

Comment: We are running git very simply, I make changes, and push. Then it's his turn.  What is sha1

Comment: It looks like it is number of commit, can you give an example.

Comment: @alex_borsody - Updated my answer on sha1 hash

Answer (score 2):

```
 git log # to check what SHA1 you need
 git checkout -b tmp SHA1 # to checkout the right SHA1 and create a tmp branch
```

If you checkout directly a SHA1, you would end up with a **[DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714)**, with the risk of making some unreferenced commits.
See for instance "[git: how to retrieve all files as of a certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161259/git-how-to-retrieve-all-files-as-of-a-certain-date)".

Note that you have various syntax to [checkout by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990484/git-checkout-by-date):

```
<refname>@{<date>}, e.g. master@{yesterday}, HEAD@{5 minutes ago}
```

Comment: Um, why did you edit and add so much???? First of all, `fetch` to go back to a commit?? And checkout by date when OP asks for **a** commit and not some commit few weeks ago. This answer is just noise now, IMO.

Comment: @manojlds: You're right that the fetch is not necessary in this particular context (though it would be in others), but otherwise the answer's quite reasonable:  it explains why you shouldn't simply check out an SHA1, and provides some potentially helpful extra information. +1.

Comment: @Jefromi - I didn't mean any disrespect to VonC. Actually, I am a fan of his answers :). Just that, he had added so many things ( I was about to delete my answer when I saw that I had given the same answer as him!) , which may confuse a newbie.