# Tortoisegit pull preserve timestamp

Tags: git, timestamp, pull, tortoisegit

Is there a way to preserve the timestamp of a file when its pulled using tortoisegit? Bitbucket commit history says the files were modified 3 days or x days back. But when a pull is done with tortoisegit the modified timestamp of the file shows todays or current date-time and not the historical date in bitbucket.

While using tortoisesvn this was possible but its not happening in tortoise git. Any pointers in how to go about this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a matter of turtoisegit, or even a matter of Windows, it's just the normal Git behaviour. When doing a clone/pull, files are taking the timestamp of when they are created/updated locally.

This question has already been asked, here for example: [Git restore file date creation after clone on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570217/git-restore-file-date-creation-after-clone-on-windows). You can follow the links in the comment for further explanations.