# Sharing your public key inside Git repository | Push arbitrary Git object to a remote

Tags: git

In Git, one can store objects in Git's storage with `git hash-object`. That's what I do, to store my public key, which I use to sign Git tags - inspired by this chapter in Git book - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References#Tags

So, I `hash-object` my public key, create an annotated tag for it, and push the tag to a remote. And it is pushed all right. However, when other users pull changes from the remote - they don't see this tag (they see, however, other *regular* tags pointing to revisions).

So, the question is - is it possible to push to a remote an arbitrary object stored with `hash-object`? Or, otherwise, how the `junio-gpg-pub` key is actually stored in Git's Git repository?

Comment: Would a git push --all be more effective? Otheriwse, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967405/git-how-do-i-push-objects-created-with-git-hash-object-back-to-origin doesn't have yet any answer.

Comment: @VonC that question doesn't appear to me to be related to this one.

Comment: @qqx agreed. I must have read it a bit too fast. +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other users will need to use `git fetch --tags` to get the tag with your public key. The fetch command will normally only retrieve tags which point to objects which are reachable from the branches that it is retrieving; this is mentioned in the documentation of the `--tags` option. Your public key isn't part of the history, therefore it would not be automatically fetched.