# Git: Is it possible to fake the signing date of a tag?

Tags: git, security, gnupg

As a scientist I would like to keep some official record of the time I check something into my Git repository. This in order to later back up claims of who invented what first during for instance patent disputes.

At the moment I from time to time add a tag to my repository like so:

```
git tag -s -m "`date`" 2012-08-20
```

and push the tags to the central server:

```
git push --tags
```

Pulling up a tag shows the date I signed it with my key:

```
git tag -v 2012-08-20
object 2d6f6035270e8e44c035431e99be8da3fccee095
type commit
tag 2012-08-20
tagger My Full Name <name@institution> 1345466433 +0200

Mon Aug 20 14:40:33 CEST 2012
gpg: Signature made Mon Aug 20 14:40:37 2012 CEST using RSA key ID somekey
gpg: Good signature from "My Full Name <name@institution>"
gpg:                 aka "My Full Name <personal-email>"
```

My question is how secure these dates are? Is it possible tamper with them later on?

EDIT: to clarify a but further, I wish to be able to prove that it would be very unlikely that I tampered with the tags later on.

Comment: When signing executable code with Microsoft Authenticode signature, you can use a "time-stamping" service, which verifies the time that the signature was stamped, as long as you trust the time-stamping service provider. I don't know of any other way to sign something with a time-stamp, especially if it would hold up legally, but you might search for that term.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What Git guarantees is: If the date (or the rest of the tag, or the commits attached to it etc.) are altered, the SHA1 of the tag will change.

However, to make this useful, *you must somehow prove what the original SHA1 tag was, and that you already had it at the claimed date of invention*.

Otherwise, to fraudulently claim that you invented something in January 1980, you could just rewind your computer's date to 1980 and create the repository with the necessary commits, tags and all - git would not know, as it can only believe what the system clock tells it.

So if you want to prove that you invented/wrote something prior to some date in the past, git (alone) cannot help you, nor can any form of signing alone. What you need is [Trusted timestamping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping). There are various different schemes, but all require one or more third parties that essentially vouch for the correctness of the timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a certified timestamp as described by Ryan J in this recent thread [How can I use RFC3161 (trusted) timestamps to prove the age of commits in my Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11913228/717355)

This appears to be a certified, verified way of recording the sha1 of the relevant tip commit.

Answer (score 4):

You could embed your git commit sha1 into the Bitcoin blockchain by using a service such as http://www.proofofexistence.com/.