# Terraform archive_file producing different file hash and file size on Mac and Linux

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on a Terraform project to deploy Lambda functions and layers on AWS using a CI/CD pipeline. The functions are zipped using archive_file. While I can successfully deploy all resources with Terraform CLI in my CI/CD pipeline, I encounter an issue when running terraform plan on my Mac.

The problem arises when checking the output_sha256 for my layer and function. Although the function consists of a single .py file, and the layer has a more complex nested structure, only the layer's hash changes between Mac and Linux deployments.
Example of layers folder structures: `layer1/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/some-files.py`

Here is a snippet of the Terraform code:

```
data "archive_file" "test_create_address" {
  type             = "zip"
  source_dir       = "../lambda/create_address/"
  output_file_mode = "0664"
  output_path      = ".terraform/zips/test_create_address.zip"
}
```

After some testing, it seems to be related to how Mac and Linux zip up folders. I also noticed that certain folder structures produce the same size and hash on both Mac and Linux.
Example: `lambda1/folder1/folder2.1/folder3/test.py`

My question is: Why does archive_file produce differently sized zip files on Mac and Linux, and how can I ensure consistency in zip file output across these platforms?

Any insights or suggestions on addressing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I know that using Terraform cloud would solve this issues, but in my current environment that is not an option

I have committing my code to Github and running Terraform CLI to deploy my resource's successfully.
I have then tried running `terraform plan` on my local mac.

My expectation: That terraform would output `No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.`

What actually happened: terraform found changes due to diffrent hashes for my lambda layers.

I have also tried setting `output_file_mode` for all my archive files with the same issue occurring.

Comment: I think it is a mistake to assume that zip archives are always going to produce consistent hashes. Zipping the same files multiple times is not guaranteed to give you the exact same zip file hash each time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19523211/13070 And going across platforms (Linux/Mac) are definitely going to generate some differences. I've run into the same issue before with Terraform/Lambda, and switched to doing the zip in my build process outside of Terraform, and committing the zip file to source control.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about committing the the zipfiles. 
I did however find an other solution that solved the issue.
What i ended up doing was committing my `.DS_Store` files in the lambda directory. This might not be a perfect solution but it did solve my problem.