How to build a docker image in terraform only when the source files have changed
We have a way of doing this.  But it always sees changes...
  dir_hash    = sha256(join("", [for f in fileset(path.root, "../modules/gcp_gke_cluster/files/email_sender/*") : filesha256(f) if basename(f) != ".DS_Store"]))

We generate that hash and use
resource "null_resource" "docker_build" {
  triggers = {
    dir_hash = local.dir_hash_cluster_notifications
  }

But the hash generated on our workstations (mac) is different than the ones generate in our ci/cd pipelines (linux).
Seems like the sha256 values can vary even from workstation to workstation depending on what is install according to my googling.
So is there a more reliable way to do this?

interesting ... could that filesha256 be including the time?

I just tested and no the filesha256 does not care about the timestamps... could. it be that in the pipeline it is adding other files that you are not accounting for?

Some stuff I saw implied it had to do with the newline character.  But they could have been refering to windows.  Others I saw said it seemed to do with other tools installed on the mac affecting how the sha was calculated.  I saw things like "I deleted X" and now they match.  So I think the sha method just isn't reliable across OS's.

If the file is the same, the line endings should be the same ... where are this files coming from? ...  I'm hopping these files are from source control and nothing in the pipeline touches those if not all bets are off

You should provide that lists of files, ideally creating a project in GitHub that reproduces this will save a lot of time trying to figure out your issue

They are in git.  Just a dockerfile, main.py, poetry.lock, poetry.toml, pyrightconfig.json.  I am looking at things like https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv/issues/275 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571991/terraform-archive-file-producing-different-file-hash-and-file-size-on-mac-and-li.  (we aren't doing anything with zip though.  And that is why I came to the conclusion that this method just doesn't work.  Are you saying you know it to work across OS's?

from your test below it looks like I got the wrong impression from those other posts.  Let me go back to assuming it should work and dig deeper.

Of the 5 file you list are they all showing different values for the filesha256 ? it would be nice to know if this is something isolated to one file or multiple

Ok... found it.  The pyrightconfig.json was actually in some higher level .gitignore file.  So it didn't show up in CICD.  Once I added that to the exclusion list, it no longer saw a diff.  I guess those other posts I read lead me astray (well and a co-worker said they same thing).  I should have done more due diligence before assuming it wasn't expected to work.

I recommend you to do some more output, to get details in what file(s) are causing the difference, code could be something like:
locals {
  dir_hash = (
    {
      for f in fileset(path.root, "../*.tf") :
      f => filesha256(f)
    }
  )
}

output "test" {
  value = local.dir_hash
}


that will give us a break down of the files, in my case it looks like:
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = {
      + "../acm.tf"                      = "be024388d7bfbb2fad05a9dd5b128f87a8a33eff3eb4d6a8d52f01031277ede4"
      + "../api_gateway.tf"              = "ea5144bb5ea6f3c99a015046e8189ff64928442caca3473a080027160dce5ce1"
      + "../certificate.tf"              = "ddcd505f62a06922db1711b1aaf60d9f057804de34825d122dfd09fa214b350d"
      + "../count_cannot_be_computed.tf" = "5e119c6a099ad21b704e3f657178214bdd41f31c61ca49db4af25e0350a345d0"
      + "../data.tf"                     = "889cbae409b4d0fb5888290a8d432d76a83bd4c341a7bbd017a2db2a465fcc74"
      + "../ebs.tf"                      = "d92b46555390914a5ee43a24492a15ee69936cca2d2e0ba674ef6aa4875ce564"
      + "../ec2_alpine.tf"               = "d5f8bddd81a9e042da68a61305aea7df9966d73245816e75733823ae2a7cf8c0"
      + "../ec2_amzn.tf"                 = "d84596bf6ed44ea2842fcaa4eb906fa88782064134620c353efb70a36739b40c"
      + "../ec2_suse.tf"                 = "a6396e711241a9e96d78e8043eaabdd8da43c28f02ea9c684fc2782b8ffe46c3"
      + "../ec2_ubuntu.tf"               = "e556fe6a98f9f24bf609c6a6b75a140a09b768e1b17b2b8c6e0bfc6f48cc2e42"
      + "../ec2_win.tf"                  = "60e948b1736871382a6a6d2ca194647cd074e07a3f94331547cff5f849f4ae50"
      + "../ec2_wordpress.tf"            = "8bc4019dfa5fc42085dfc392dbe416426b522d84b40c372b3f6b080b7300ad5f"
      + "../efs.tf"                      = "a666d055a9c26ab4269c66b62c3f0346fc10a9acaf7aa9f8cc8ffeb7fdeafc2e"
      + "../elb.tf"                      = "b020685ef7895db5e259da9c3e73610658120e2214cb362c8c05c6a829157d39"
      + "../example.tf"                  = "8a6f6e82c9abc3267b18e54eb4dd6f006ea513c41dcb6175d2603ff3960e40d9"
      + "../fargate_service.tf"          = "fdb70ea6c9d491f6e27364aa4d60f7173c1c13e2e55d8140a7468dc14e47b7fc"
      + "../inspector.tf"                = "ae59eb526122a8030a0ee03bfb219dbd64c57768d030e03da747c6feceb68dc6"
      + "../kms.tf"                      = "cbbc073e525a4c27a43cd38d4e1652674a12ff724cb2ef1e3eae4a7e90e7ae92"
      + "../lambda_function.tf"          = "de55466924c10f772d8cb5de88f611eb071e2b2c655f32a4ea8881b2f3d3aa41"
      + "../local_file.tf"               = "b8c9a3bdc25e96d5abc5e698af3b2cac56f796bd0ec2ad9c211499ad5ff134ab"
      + "../null_res.tf"                 = "fc0c2ec768cfa41a19f5b26928f04c4f23d17411fff152252942e9815886e352"
      + "../output.tf"                   = "c6aa022d66294d1ba0cab9d9dd553052e6786ff15e8a723a92d47a69c0828fa0"
      + "../s3.tf"                       = "1a268081029768971e31f795678aa17c139c713f8ba3c626f3f4de70b714aca9"
      + "../sg.tf"                       = "32ba82e3f184a5ed31900fcdb985e1e76f5aa2e8ee27e460a93e055f36bf153b"
      + "../template.tf"                 = "f0bf5c81d269c38d296e71d6a27f7224b4be133d78eef95fb737fd0a95901680"
      + "../variables.tf"                = "7fe638f0ea4e5a9165f71fd49abe3a4dcb5b4cc77d5e6578f01f7f235259ae27"
      + "../vpc.tf"                      = "88ab343e138fdc465f63985b0f84574c0a0996086fc2cb4c666338298a2510d5"
      + "../vpn.tf"                      = "0266ef4ca62e461209107af2957800b4f6fad7675a6c0e38f16c2aead0d9ea76"
    }

hopefully it will be as easy as excepting a couple more files like you did for the ".DS_Store" worst case at least we will have more details on what is causing the difference
Tests
I tested on two machines that happen to have different version of terraform...
The same results on both.
Terraform v1.7.0
on linux_amd64

Terraform v1.6.2
on darwin_amd64


There are only like 5 files left.  And all are relevant to the build.  But my understanding from other posts on the subject is that the issue is the macOS vs linux and so all of the files will diff.

@Jack-of-some I just tested on two different machines same results

See comments above.  There was one file that was actually in a higher level gitignore, so CI CD didn't have that file.  I was weak and allowed myself to be lead astray from expecting this to work.
