# Is it possible to add a file to a git repo keeping its original date?

Tags: git, date, addition

When we performed a "git add" the date of file was changed to current date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking out old file WITH original create/modified timestamps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722/checking-out-old-file-with-original-create-modified-timestamps)

Answer (score 1):

`git` does not track time stamps and it does not change your file timesatmp when you add it to the stage area.

Here is a live demo to show you that git does not care about dates. git only track content and in some cases file mode (chmod)

[image]