# Can I use a file's last committed time as the Windows Date Modified timestamp?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

Is there a way to set Windows Explorer to display a file's last committed date in the Date Modified field instead of showing the last downloaded date? Or maybe an additional column that does this?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.

Custom columns in Windows Explorer were supported until Windows XP, so there is no technical way right now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! When we used TortoiseSVN with Subversion on Windows 7, there was an option to make the Date Modified column change. I think it was called "Set file dates to last 'commit' time". Is this a Subversion feature that isn't possible with Git?

Comment: No, that's no possible for Git (TortoiseSVN != TortoiseGit). That option in TortoiseSVN touches all files according to the last modification time - it does not change the column. However, there are workaround such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/2179722/3906760 which I did not test.