# Is there a way to preserve the file created time during checkout in git?

Tags: git, macos

I would like to have the original created time of the file preserved for files in git. Currently if I create a file from iOS today and syncs it to my mac git server. Then fetches the changes tomorrow from Fork on mac, the newly created file will show the created date as tomorrow instead of the original date of today. Is it possible to retain the original date on a checkout? Thanks.

Comment: I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722/checking-out-old-files-with-original-create-modified-timestamps but I am not sure if it works for iOS and macOS setup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking out old files WITH original create/modified timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722/checking-out-old-files-with-original-create-modified-timestamps) The OS is not the restricting factor here, it's a restriction of git itself that it doesn't store/recreate timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not store any timestamps for individual files at all.  It will not overwrite files that are considered up to date according to the index in order to preserve the modification time, but when it needs to update the working tree, it will always use the current time.  This is important because it honours the way Make works.

However, you ask specifically about the creation time.  This value is not specified by POSIX and there's no portable way to set it or access it at all, and some systems and file systems don't even have it.  Git doesn't know anything about it or use it in any way, so any tool you had to modify it would be specific to macOS and dependent on whether macOS lets you do that.  I'm not aware of any such functionality.

If you need to set the *modification time* or permissions to a specific value for some reason, macOS ships with the `mtree` command, and you can create (and if necessary, edit) a manifest, and then use `mtree -u` or `mtree -U` with that manifest to set the modification time or permissions appropriately.