# Creating and using a Mercurial repository for system files

Tags: linux, mercurial

I've been using [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) successfully for my programming projects for quite some time, so it was a logical step to let it handle the rest of my versioning needs as well. The first step in this direction would be to have Mercurial handle the configuration files that I modify manually on my Linux system. Unfortunately, I seem to have hit a few snags here:

1. Mercurial does not store file metadata (ownership, permissions, extended attributes).
2. Mercurial will not handle files that do not reside in the repository directory.

I believe that I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291508/507519) for (1), although it apparently involves modifying the source of a separate [utility](http://david.hardeman.nu/software.php#metastore) and a bit of [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) magic.

The second point seems trickier: I do not want to place a Mercurial repository at the filesystem root (`/`), for a variety of reasons. Unfortunately - for what is admittedly [a very good reason](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue1620) - Mercurial will not handle files that reside outside the repository root, either directly or through symbolic links.

I could probably write a wrapper script that would use e.g. [`mount --bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3011985/507519) or [unionfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) to allow Mercurial to access the root filesystem. I wrote a similar script in the past, but it was by no means transparent and I had to jump through a lot of hoops while using it - doing it correctly would be tricky, especially if I want to handle absolute file paths.

At this point I am starting to feel that I'd have to pile a lot of home-grown solutions on top of each other to make Mercurial work in this use case - perhaps too many. There would always be rough edges that I'd occasionally hit.

- Is there an existing *complete* solution for this use case? A Mercurial extension or a wrapper script that would allow `hg` to work transparently with system files?
- Alternatively - and quite reluctantly - is there a *modern* version control system or other versioning solution that will do this out of the box?

Comment: With personal config files (all the dot-files in the user directory), you usually create symlinks from the expected place to the actual file in the repo... have you considered doing that here?

Comment: @Ludovic: would *you* do that for `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: I wouldn't indeed, but that's mostly because I wouldn't put it in Mercurial in the first place. Those files are unlikely to be the same between my computers (unless you're in charge of a farm with all identical PCs), and are unlikely to change much within the lifespan of a single computer (not to the point where I would need revision control on it at least).

My point was mostly to discuss doing it the other way: instead of bringing outside files into the repo, how about bring repo files to the outside? But "no I can't/won't" is a valid answer to that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a straight-forward solution using `git`. More specifically, `git` allows the work directory (*work tree* in `git` terms) to reside away from the repository itself. Thefore all I have to do is:

- Create a secure directory in the desired location:

  ```
  # mkdir -p /root/git
  # chmod 700 /root/git
  ```
- Initialize a `git` repository within the previous directory:

  ```
  # cd /root/git
  # git init
  ```
- Modify `.git/config` to contain the `core.worktree` option, by adding `worktree = /etc` in the `[core]` section
- Use `git` normally:

  ```
  # git add /etc/hosts
  # git commit -m "..." -a
  ```

Answer (score 2):

> Alternatively - and quite reluctantly - is there a modern version
>   control system or other versioning solution that will do this out of
>   the box?

[Flyback](http://flyback-project.org/) (similar to Apple's "Time Machine") is not a VCS, but if all you want is a linear history, it might be exactly what you need.

Comment: +1 It's not what I need, but it does sound very interesting for other use cases.