# Default permissions when Mercurial creates files

Tags: mercurial

If Mercurial [does not track file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289816/can-mercurial-be-made-to-preserve-file-permissions) by default, how does it decide on the permissions for any files/directories it creates?

Does it use `umask`?  If not, what does it use?

I have [read in the mail list](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/umask-and-permissions-issue-td799086.html) the following:

```
Mercurial uses the mode of the .hg/store directory to compute a mask
```

but this seems a bit arbitrary (if there is any explanation behind it, I'd love to hear it). Is this explained in the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any complete explanation, only a mention of it in the "[How To Handle Multiple Committers](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MultipleCommitters)" page:

> If you are using a version of Mercurial older than 1.0, it's important that each user's `umask` be set to `002` or something similar. If it's set to `022`, group write privileges will be masked off for files that users create, causing other users to be unable to modify them.
>
> You can change the default `umask` for a user by editing their `~/.profile` and adding the line...

```
umask 002
```

> Alternatively, you can edit `/etc/profile` to change the system-wide settings.
>   Changing the `/etc/profile` will not work if people check in stuff with the `hg` command, as that file isn't read by non-interactive shells, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is a better place to put the system-wide settings.
>
> Otherwise since Mercurial 1.0, the default permission is inherited from .hg/store.